# My first experience with the "Ask a question" Wizard was infuriating

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, asking-questions, ask-question-wizard-2018

I understand what you're trying to do with the new wizard, but so far it has me pulling my hair out.  Is there no way to disable "guided mode" for those who don't need it?

Am I the only person finding it terribly unusable?  Every time I click somewhere, it changes how things are displayed and resets me to the top of the page.  Also, every time I insert a carriage return, it pops to the top and sometimes removes my focus, causing me to have to click in the editor again, popping me back to the top of the page.

Can we please have a way to disable it?  I can't tell you how refreshing it has been typing my question here in meta.  There has to be a better solution.

Comment: Hmm, definitely not supposed to be scrolling / changing focus like that while typing. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I've tried it in both Chrome and Safari on Mac.  I think *maybe* it behaves slightly better in Chrome, but most of the problems were in both.

Comment: Not able to see New Contributor here

Comment: An _escape from this evil wizard_ button is a good suggestion imo. Also for feedback, because then you can measure how often users want to escape it.

Comment: On the plus side: if this puts a stop on the influx of low quality questions ... I give you this is an unintended side-effect ... (all in good spirits here, bring your sense of humor) ... ;)

Comment: you want to get rid of the wizard, having read this I want nothing more than to be able to see it. I guess I could create a second account...

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth An "escape" button would entirely defeat the wizard, and hence the problem it is intended to address...

Comment: I'm very curious because this sounds like basic usability that definitely should have been caught in testing. Are you using any browser extensions? What happens if you try using the wizard in an incognito window and/or with a new browser user profile? A video of the poor experience you're having would certainly help the devs to track this down quicker.

Comment: @IanKemp The aim is to provide guidance for those who need it, as I understand it. If someone has looked around properly and there's a (non-obvious) way to speed up the process, that's probably not harmful. They can always just write the question in notepad and copy-paste, at least this way SE can track stats consciously (how many do that, is quality lower or higher for the users that do)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The wizard is intentionally a barrier to asking low-effort questions. As soon as you give an "escape hatch", knowledge of it will get out into the wild and EVERYONE will use it. Unfortunately it's all or nothing.

Comment: @IanKemp That's certainly not how I understand it. It shouldn't be _here's an annoying wizard to make sure you at least put in the effort to click through the wizard, and filter out the users not willing to click a couple of times_. It's _you're a beginner to this site and know little about it, here's a wizard that can help_. The wizard isn't supposed to be a barrier at all. And the point the wizard is addressing is a lack of knowledge, people that follow details like this should likely be able to escape it.

Comment: @Shog9 FYI, I can repro in Firefox, [here is a screenrecording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI1Tl.gif) of a state I got in. Just clicking in the editor makes it jump around. I think my last action was that I clicked on one of the guidance texts, instead of and editable part of the textarea.

Comment: @rene looks like several pages in the wizard progress bar at the top get activated

Comment: @IanKemp finding out how to circumvent the barrier implies some kind of research, exactly what is usually missing with poor questions.

Comment: @Holger - Except when how becomes common knowledge. "Ask over on Stack Overflow. Be sure to X the Y to get out of the wizard so you can just type."

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you mean like “Ask over on Stack Overflow. Be sure to be precise and clear and to provide all necessary information.” became common knowledge? I’m not even sure whether beginners would actually try to get out of the wizard. Rather, they use whatever wizard they find, even if in implies marking source code of an arbitrary language as JavaScript snippet. And if they want to, just make the complexity of the assistant circumvention higher than the complexity of asking a not-so-pure question.

Comment: @Holger - The low- or zero-effort types will absolutely share how to get past anything requiring effort with their low- or zero-effort type friends.

Comment: My experience using Chrome vLatest: The issue seems to be that about 2 pages of guidance are "inserted" on top, every time you click in one of the editable areas. So the user needs to scroll down 2 pages after every click, just to get back to where they clicked, with little or no indication that scrolling would even help. How this passed UX or QA is beyond me...

Comment: To all of the comments saying that the intent is to force people to use this to prevent them from asking a bad question [Tim has specifically confirmed that that's not the case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing#comment657731_378089).  When this is out of testing, users will be able to freely move between the wizard and the current form.  This is designed to be a way to help people ask better questions who *want the help*, and want to be guided.  If you want it to be non-optional, then propose that change, because that's not the plan.

Comment: When we initially talked about this, we were going to include a way for new folks to turn this off, but it could be that doing so really complicated how the test was structured in the system (I'm going to find out about it). The scrolling is something I have not been able to reproduce so that's just .. delightful .. because it could mean it's a bug that people with the developer bit set on their account aren't seeing. DAG is getting to the bottom of it, I'll have updates at some point soon, I'm just waiting for folks to get in.

Comment: @TimPost It would probably be wise to disable it immediately until you figure this out.

Comment: One would hope they have a test account to use that does not have the developer bit set on their account to truly emulate a user with whatever parameters are necessary...

Comment: Why not just use the Github style free form templates and let people fill them in. If the question doesn't match the template and it is from a low rep user and doesn't make a lick of sense, it makes it easier to downvote or close.

Comment: @Chloe You probably want to discuss that [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing) instead.  This is a question about a particular bug, not a general discussion of the feature.

Comment: @ErikA I would presume that the site admins intended it to serve **both** purposes that you describe. And yes, an *escape this evil wizard* button is sorely needed haha!

Answer (score 20):

This should be fixed now, thanks for the report. 
Sorry for the confusion-- my name's Jane and I'm new at Stack Overflow. The state change here is created with a Flags enum that didn't have a 0 so that was accidentally added in last minute for style, but it (clearly) did some weird things with the functionality. 
Thanks again for looking out!

Comment: Confusing. We really need to [get you non-diamond employees some kind of marker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310518/can-we-have-a-square-or-triangle-or-heart-or-something-after-employees-names)!

Comment: How do we know this account isn't just some random imposter with the profile description of "Developer at Stack Overflow"? And if it's not an imposter, what was fixed? OP mentioned a variety of issues - was there a complete overhaul? Are users able to disable this now?

Comment: Hey, y'all! Jane is one of our awesome devs, diamond or no. She's doing a lot of the heavy lifting on the AaQ Wizard and we're glad to have her around.

Comment: @dwirony I added more context here in my answer

Comment: @Catija Ty for the verification! And thank you Jane.

Comment: Your about page is funny.

Comment: The only person impersonating someone that works here is me.