# Can the new 'Ask-Question-Wizard' appear to users at-will as well?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, ask-question-wizard-2018

Can the new 'Ask Question Wizard' appear to *everyone* at the click of a button? I seem to find the Wizard quite effective in its job, and think that it is unfair if it appears to new users only, and that also with only a 50-50 chance. I would quite like it if I could access it whenever I want while typing a question. This is because, believe it or not, even experts sometimes need help in typing questions (I am no expert). I'm sure others would agree with me as well.

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369682/4751173) mentioned a preview at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard, but that page doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 6):

The wizard isn't even finished yet. Its recent deployment is [only a test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057/1709587). The feature you're asking for is [currently one that the staff intend to implement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing?cb=1#comment657428_378057) before the final version goes live, but not now, because the entire point of the 50-50 chance is to allow them to scientifically evaluate the impact of the wizard on question quality.

Comment: That 50/50 chance is only for "some combination of:... (criteria)", all linked to low reputation and/or New Contributors. Don't you think it would be helpful if higher reputation contributors could have a look at it as well? Even a bare URL would be enough. I'd rate it unlikely masses of high-rep users trying it out would skew the results by a significant percentage.

Comment: @usr2564301 Sure, it would be helpful to have an easier way for Meta users to check it out for the sake of commenting on it. That's not what's being asked for in this question, though.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to tell if someone specifically turned it on, versus the 50-50 test, and therefore just leave them out of the testing? Then you can have Meta users actually try it themselves?

Comment: Adding to this, it is easy for them to checkout user reputation when they ask a question with the wizard.

Comment: "because the entire point of the 50-50 chance is to allow them to scientifically evaluate the impact of the wizard on question quality." The feature that is requested here is not really impeding the ability to scientifically evaluate the impact (unless everyone opts to choose the wizard henceforth, which would be a good indicator of quality by itself).