# Spooked by robotic/repetitive questions in the First Post review

Tags: discussion, questions, ask-question-wizard-2018

While going through the First Post review in the last few days I have noticed something weird. A lot of new posters are now putting lines like "Did research, found nothing", "No code", or "Look online for documentation found nothing". I have never seen this type of robotic content before with such...frequency. In addition, these lines are pretty much always separated by a line in between. A verbatim example:

> Checked the settings of Xcode
>
> No code relevant for this question
>
> Expect to have the simulator run in the Xcode window

My first thought was that there is an influx of bots writing questions but that seems silly. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Yesterday's [Dilbert comic](https://dilbert.com/strip/2019-01-07) is oddly appropriate.

Comment: This looks very much like they went through the ask a question wizard. They put their question in the first box, and the three lines you've shown here are them answering the prompts presented: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAd8g.png

Comment: @Rob those hints should really be rephrased. It's way too easy to answer them too vaguely to be useful.

Comment: I don't think it is more frequent now than before. I've seen (and edited out) those "searched a lot" for long time. I always read "searched and found nothing" as "I went to https://www.disney.com/ and searched but found nothing about my swift question"... it makes reading such questions at least a bit more amusing :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think it is time we stir up Twitter to complain about that disney.com site not being friendly for Swift developers ...

Comment: After you have overcome the spookiness, don't forget to downvote and vote to close the question.

Comment: I noticed this on a question I previously answered as well, in fact I made [a feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378548/3270037) for the wizard to either leave the prompts or prompt users to add their own context

Comment: @Rob that screenshot is the currently tested wizard!? No wonder. Might I suggest it be a bit more verbose. In it's current form, it actually encourages writing posts like "asked my friend, I don't know, tried hard". Even Twitter's "What's on your mind" is more encouraging :D

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I guess these are questions from users that used the new [Ask question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing?cb=1).

[image: Screenshot of the wizard prototype, showing the guiding statements]

This wizard provides a guided mode that adds different "content sections" to the question. If the user sloppily "answers" those, you get this robotic content after the guiding rails are removed. It's pretty much like getting the transcript of only one half of a conversation:

**Provide background and tell us what you've already tried:**

> Checked the settings of Xcode

**Show your code.**

> No code relevant for this question

**Describe the expected and actual results:**

> Expect to have the simulator run in the Xcode window

Comment: Seems like it, though I am not sure it is good design... Seems like this is somewhat addressed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378221/2865814) (Discalimer: not my post). So if you don't like how its done, it might be worth it to support that answer.

Comment: I was vaguely aware of the wizard but didn't know it had these prompts. Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

This is, as others have pointed out, an artifact of the question wizard. We're still in the first iteration. There were options and words that quite a few of us wanted to tweak a bit more prior to shipping, but at some point you just have to *get it out there* and *let it make a bit of a mess* so you can see what's going to happen in actual cases, optimize it from there, and test some more.

We really appreciate everyone's patience with this and hope you don't mind editing where it makes sense to help folks. We knew some questions might look a little disjointed (as if you were reading one part of a conversation), but we didn't anticipate that looking like an attack from our robot overlords.

A wizard that successfully guides people through navigating Stack Overflow's *many* possible quirks and customs is our goal, and it's *insanely* hard to do in a manner that is welcoming and not onerous to someone that is brand new to the site and just learning how to program. This is something we can learn from (and perhaps infer new subtle archetypes when we put the final question together). A box that lets someone say "I don't have any code, my question is about a programming tool" *could* let us switch to a template that is better suited for someone asking a question about, say, Git.

But I really, really, *really* want to look at the numbers from the test group and any static analysis we do from the questions produced through it before we go changing stuff. We've introduced structure where there wasn't any, so we have to get a baseline of what structure vs no structure looks like, and then we can start looking at what changes to that structure do, and we're at least a few more iterations away from that.

So, we appreciate y'all putting up with it while we whittle this down. We're not obtuse (other answers on related posts kind of imply we don't realize what we're doing or optimizing for) -- we do, and we also know it's going to take a lot longer to get to the version that many people think we should have shipped initially while actually testing it responsibly (that's why we hired all those fancy UX experts and researchers and such).

Comment: "Just learning how to program" - It's been pretty clear that there's at least a minor barrier to entry, and that some ability *to* program is required to properly participate.  Are we trying to attract users that do not have the ability to meet that bar at all?  If so, that will just lead to a bad user experience all around.

Comment: @fbueckert No. If (and this is one whopper of an if) we can execute this front-end wizard properly (and note, I'm not pro killing of wizards!) one might _casually_ realize that they have a bit more work to do prior to asking where they currently do _not_, and thus, return when they feel a little more prepared. What we want are people that have some ability to _understand_ the answers they get while writing questions that aren't onerous to comprehend. I may be reaching for something so high I'll never quite get it, but that's where I am with expectations, if it helps.

Comment: I'm totally on board with making sure those expectations are set right up front.  Doing it anywhere else not only sets the user up for failure, but fails the site as well as curators get ahold of it, and now the user is fighting with them.  It'd be nice that if a casual method to indicate low quality is ignored, the system straight up blocks the question from being posted.  I'm not sure how effective it would be, as users love working around blocks, but stemming the tide of quality absent content is very important, I feel.

Comment: I have an idea. Perhaps, if users are using the question wizard, you can inject the questions that they see directly into the question when they post them. That way other users get the appropriate context.

Comment: These questions reveal that the wizard leads users to treat asking a question as merely a matter of filling out a form. This is the exact opposite of how users should approach writing a question; they need to have some level of writing skills and need to be able to evaluate how their question will be read. They need to think carefully about how they are communicating and put as much work into their question writing as we expect them to put into attempting to solve their own problem. I don't see any way to measure that. How are you going to alleviate that?

Comment: Maybe a two part wizard: first one short, similar to current one, second one much longer, with examples.

Comment: "you don't mind editing where it makes sense to help folks" I do mind editing questions, *just like this example* created mindlessly by poster's who do not have the professionalism or enthusiasm to write a clear question.

Comment: Perhaps the form needs to start at a different level and ask: Is this question about 1) Existing code that's not working? 2) A problem using a programming tool 3) and so on - to cover the types of questions valid on the site... and then *n*) about learning a programming language *n*) anything else not on-topic - and go from there to a follow-up with appropriate guidance for asking that kind of question, including the message "It appears Stack Overflow is not the correct place to ask your question." followed by the usual description of what's on-topic for the site or a link to that information.