# Spurned authors deleting their questions after they are closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I've been monitoring the [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag for some time now and every and now then users get really angry when some of their questions get closed as a duplicate of a well-discussed and clearly explained Q/A post. I constantly see in the comments that they would no longer visit the site as it's not welcoming to them. Though I constantly try to explain as clearly as I can how the linked question resolves the problem, they are not just ready to take it.

Sometimes it just feels bad for ruining the experience of a user visiting this great site. How could this situation be handled better?

Comment: I guess you're talking about [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381428/question-closed-unreasonably)?

Comment: @BDL: Yes it is

Comment: A related discussion that seems to be pretty similar: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-vote-to-close-questions-and-be-welcoming-at-the-same-time  Might be worth reading it.

Comment: Also, @Inian, it seems like the reason for this particular user's ragequit was that his Meta question got downvoted, not necessarily that his SO question got dupe-hammered. This ties into this recent post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381212/is-the-intensity-of-meta-working-in-our-favor-or-to-our-detriment re non-Meta-frequenting users not understanding that Meta downvotes are consensus, not points.

Comment: Finally, @Inian, there is a reason you are a gold badge holder and he is not. Everything I've seen from your interaction with this user shows that not only were you courteous to a fault, you were perfectly correct in dupe-hammering his question. *Never* let yourself be bullied into acting against Stack Overflow's quality purely because doing so upsets someone!

Comment: Since the original meta post the question on main was deleted, undeleted, reopened, got two additional answers... and was finally closed again. What a mess.

Comment: @yivi: Looks like another gold hammer closed it. Seriously, if it got re-opened against the first gold hammer, a second gold hammer close looks really _really_ bad. The answer was so hard to find in the target question I added a direct link to it.

Comment: @Joshua, the first reopen was the original closer to let other users chime in. Then another close vote was casted, and then a second gold badge closed.

Comment: _"We don't want spoiled children on this site."_ SE citation needed...

Comment: Last week someone left a comment calling me a "shithead" because I told him what he did wrong instead of leaving a cut/paste answer.  Rather than being annoyed I found it mildly amusing - behaving like children indeed! Later I found the comment deleted, I don't know if he had second thoughts or if it got flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: If I ask a duplicate, it's on me. It takes what, 1 minute or two of extra work to put in that extra little research to see if there is a similar answer? I feel that some people just come straight to SO when they run into a problem without doing "their" due diligence to solve it on their own. You have to stop bad question asking behavior as best you can, and the users won't leave, where else are they going to get their answer? Other help forums are outright derogatory with answers like 'ever hear of google dumbass?' and far worse. The user will return to SO, or their won't get issues fixed.

Comment: @canon Well, considering that SO is for professional and enthusiast programmers, that comes with some set expectations as to professionalism, and that you're going to be treated as an adult.  That's going to include interacting with others in at least a respectful manner, and while many fail to live up that ideal, it's still supposed to be a starting assumption.  It's telling how constructive a conversation is going to be when the other side doesn't.

Comment: That seems to be more _our_ standard than SE's lately.

Comment: @canon That's a fair point, but until SE explicitly tells us that bad beginner questions are allowed, that's the bar I'm using to treat users.  And once they do, I'm gone.

Comment: @fbueckert The [State of the Stack](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/18/state-of-the-stack-2019-a-year-in-review/) specifically says that SO is for "everyone who codes". That absolutely doesn't mean that poorly-asked questions are allowed but it does mean that beginner questions are allowed, provided they're well-asked.

Comment: @Catija How do you define that?  Professional and enthusiast programmers is what we're using now; if you're lowering that bar, well, now we know why you're on this massive welcoming push.  [Previous requests for clarification have confirmed there is a barrier to entry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378753/spooked-by-robotic-repetitive-questions-in-the-first-post-review/378769#comment661548_378769).

Comment: @fbueckert "Everyone" means everyone. Whether that's a scientist who has to write a script or a high school student taking their first classes or someone who just has a cool idea for an app but is trying to figure out how to do something very specific. We're still not a tutorial site, questions need to be specific and clearly defined... The thing is, the quality of question is irrelevant to experience. People with 20 years in the industry can ask bad questions, too... and people who are just starting can ask awesome ones. Level of experience isn't an indicator!

Comment: Also... "enthusiast" is kinda vague... and quite subjective. Anyone in those three categories I listed could consider themselves an "enthusiast" but that doesn't mean that you or I or... Skeet will consider them one or agree on whether they qualify, necessarily. We want good content. We don't want to restrict who can create it.

Comment: @Catija I use [Jeff's definition](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/): "People who either already have a job as a programmer, or could potentially be hired as a programmer today if they wanted to be."  That's what the site was built on.  That carries set expectations of behaviour and minimum skill level, to the point that askers can actually understand the answers.  That's a bit more strict than is needed, I think, but that's the barrier I feel needs to be maintained; it hasn't been, and that's led to this massive welcoming backlash.

Comment: If instead the barrier is, "Everyone who codes", how do you actually *define* that?  There are no set expectations at *all* there.  That is likely one of the primary reasons SO is treated like a help desk.  I don't think expecting users to conduct themselves with a modicum of professionalism is at all unreasonable.

Comment: @fbueckert That's the point. It's absurdly easy to define. It's everyone. You seem to be looking for a caveat. There isn't one. But you're ignoring the main real limiter... it's about **quality**, not passing bars of expectation of some magical "you've done enough in the industry to pass as a 'real programmer'". We're in a world where more and more of the items we interact with or work we do can be aided by the ability to program something. **If you can ask a good, ontopic, researched question, you can ask it here.** We're not going to check your bonafides.

Comment: @Catija It literally has nothing to with gatekeeping or checking bonafides.  It's about the set expectations that come with that barrier; we don't care if you're Groot on the other side of the keyboard.  As long as you can type coherently and meet our standards, you're good.  But all this focus on, "everyone" destroys that expectation entirely.  You're saying there is no expectation at all.  No professionalism required.  No research required.  No respect required.  That's a problem.

Comment: @fbueckert So... we're saying the same thing. We just define it differently. Being able to do what you (we both) expect doesn't require being a "programmer", though. And that's where we disagree.

Comment: @Catija Are we, though?  I said that Jeff's definition was a little strict, sure.  But I like the expectations that are inherent with it, and I think that's important.  It communicates a level of decorum and ability that is missing in "Everyone who codes".  I think that's a problem that needs addressing; we already get treated like a help desk enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190307/discussion-between-fbueckert-and-catija).

Comment: @MarkRansom FYI it got "caught" and deleted by moderators (I'm not a mod but I know since I checked our logs).

Comment: @Inian, considering this post is linked to my question about sed, is there any way you could update your question to clarify that I am not the person who said "in the comments that they would no longer visit the site as it's not welcoming to them"? I did delete my Meta post, and I did comment on how unwelcoming the site is, but I didn't say anything about leaving.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

> I constantly see in the comments that they would no longer visit the site as it's not welcoming to them.

Truth be told, if someone can't take constructive criticism or disagreement without feeling personally offended, then they shouldn't be on the internet. You are judging the question, not the person; the person is irrelevant.

The meme that "SO is not welcoming" has gone on for way too long and is just utter tripe. People just seem to feed it off whenever things don't go their way on this site. I have no doubt that it was originally started by people who didn't understand how SO works: i.e., that it requires some effort.

**Side Note:** Somehow, people have forgotten that the person asking for the *free* help should be courteous enough to provide *all* the information and show respect. It isn't a one-way street where the "seasoned" curators / helpers / answerers have to be "welcoming" while being pushed around.

> Though I constantly try to explain as clearly as I can how the linked question resolves the problem, **they are not just ready to take it**.

You hit the nail on the head!

Sometimes people don't listen because *they* just *don't* want to be wrong and in those instances you should just move on. There is nothing more to be gained by wasting your valuable time *trying* to explain to those individuals.

- OP asked a question
- You closed the question
- OP turned to Meta for the question to be opened
- Meta gave its opinion overwhelmingly
- OP didn't like the response they received and rather than accepting it for what it was, left a comment (which I would class as "unfriendly") and tried to take the high ground with their victim mentality.

> Sometimes it just feels bad for ruining the experience of a user visiting this great site.

Don't.

I was the one that left the comment linking the OP with the meta discussion and I skimmed over the comments, and you did nothing wrong and were not "unwelcoming". Don't be a doormat for these individuals – that's what they want.

> How could this situation be handled better?

By you? I would say try to pick up on when a user is genuinely not understanding you vs. a user being pigheaded and just do your thing (VTC, down-vote etc) and move on. Though, I realize this can be hard to do at times.

Other than that? Keep doing what you're are doing. Your contributions are - no doubt - much appreciated in your respective tags.

Comment: I'm not going to lie; this answer made me fist pump.

Comment: _"the person is irrelevant"_ That should be on the welcome wagon...

Comment: "the person is irrelevant" That should be on the unwelcome wagon...

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos When voting on posts, are you voting because of who posted it, or the content of the post?  That distinction is critical.

Comment: Yeah if you yank "the person is irrelevant" out of context you can make it sound as unfriendly as your personal agenda wants it to be.

Comment: @Gimby basically, Twitter. Excerpts of what people say posted purposely out of context to cause controversy.

Comment: @fbueckert The question indeed. Alas the phrase "You are judging the question, not the person, the person is irrelevant" puts unnecessary emphasis on the irrelevancy of the person. "You are judging the question, not the person." would convey the same meaning and would be way more *welcoming*. Most people are not fond of being judged after all, thus it is a positive.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos People aren't fond of it, I agree.  But that distinction is *critical* to how the site works.  It's what leads to all the expectation disconnects we have with new users, and why their disconnect leads to such an unwelcoming feeling.  Just as we feel unwelcome by being treated as a helpdesk.  I feel that phrase emphasizes where our focus is; the content, and the content *alone*.  That focus is why SE is so successful.

Comment: What @fbueckert said is my opinion in this. The strong nature of my emphasis was intentional to get the point across, I was being blunt on purpose.

Comment: @Script47 There is fine line between bluntness and lack of politeness. Another example is "then they shouldn't be on the internet" which is rude in my humble opinion and should rather be "then they should learn to take constructive criticism or disagreement without feeling personally offended".

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos I absolutely *could* reword a lot of this post to make it "nicer" but that wasn't the point of this post. A high rep user felt bad and thought that they had potentially done something wrong to turn someone away so I wrote in no uncertain terms what I thought so it couldn't be misunderstood. If by reading this post some people get offended but a group of active curators feel defended, I'll be pleased. Look through my previous posts / encounters with users, it'll seem completely out of character. I stand by what I wrote and how I wrote it.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Then we're just back to the whole policing comments shtick.  At the end of the day, if someone wants to be offended by something, they will be, no matter how friendly you try to word something.  Rudeness and friendliness are very subjective standards, and trying to appease everyone just leads to ineffective statements that have no real guidance.  If someone is trying to help in good faith, without being snarky or judgemental, that meets my standard.

Comment: Even though the author _should_ be irrelevant for the purpose of curating content, it seems pretty natural for people to have their ego and feelings (to one degree or another) bound up in their posts. Time and again we've seen people personally insulted by the negative reception (warranted or otherwise) their content receives. Some of us might even admit to having felt a similar pang of displeasure in our own first experience with meta. We chose to stick it out... but should everyone have to in order to benefit from meta?

Comment: *Truth be told, if someone can't take constructive criticism or disagreement without feeling personally offended, then they shouldn't be on the internet.* This kind of judgemental talking-down (and given the comments, *intentionally* judgemental) is what will make SO suffer in the long run. Write a blog post if you are so interested in expounding on who should or should not use the internet.

Comment: @jpp are you telling me that we should tolerate people unwilling to budge from their own opinion all while catering for them? I'm not talking down on anyone, I'm merely stating that if you can't take criticism then the Internet (where people can anonymously troll, insult and harm you) is not a place for you.

Comment: *Some* tolerance is required.

Comment: @Makoto absolutely, but where to draw the line? What I've wrote above is what I "think", my actions are actually completely different. I can (have been and will) separate the two.

Comment: "You are judging the question, not the person" - this is a nice idea *in theory*, and a good way to decide how you, as a "judge", should behave (e.g. don't visit their profile and downvote all their posts, or launch personal attacks, as a result of what they posted, because that's judging the person). Although this sort of falls apart in practice, since most people have at least some personal attachment to what they produce, so judging that is judging them. So I'd argue SO is fundamentally not particularly welcoming, but only in as far as necessary to enforce quality standards.

Comment: There are good points to be made in favour of closing (and downvoting) questions, especially as duplicates - I can't help but feel trying to justify your actions by arguing that those on the receiving end are rude and disrespectful and they are too easily offended / other places are worse is hurting your argument more than it's helping.

Comment: @Dukeling sorry, I'm not following you, what actions am I trying to justify here? Are you talking about VTC / down-voting? If so, that was generic statement, meaning, **IF you were ORIGINALLY going to VTC / down-vote, then just do that but don't engage the user in the comments as the OP did, this way prevents confrontation.** In no way am I saying that you should VTC / down-vote legitimate questions just because an OP is rude, vote based on the merits of a question, not flaws of the user.

Comment: SO's policies are designed to make users more rigorous… If some people feel offended because of it, and they're not willing to grow as a person, it really should be *their* loss. They can always come back later after they've grown up a little.

Comment: @Dukeling Script47 isn't the one who brought the personality of the offended askers into the argument. The OP of this Meta thread was asking, more or less, "When I close questions, sometimes people get angry. Should I avoid closing those questions to avoid the anger?" It's perfectly valid to reply "No, their anger is unreasonable and should be ignored." There is only the loosest sense in which that amounts to using the askers' character to justify actions, and it's a sense in which *any* possible answer defending the moderation actions would at least implicitly be doing the same thing.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert anecdotally, that's what I did. I do believe I've still got some ancient emails of me requesting my account to be deleted as I didn't get how the site works, I didn't ask for the system to be changed to cater for me. Since then, I've grown and matured and I've come to adore how SO works. No nonsense, no fluff, just real Q&A.

Comment: @Script47 That's why I felt I had to comment as well. I know SO's rigor has made me more rigorous, better! Drop this quality (which is pretty rare in an age of YT comments or unfiltered Quora questions!) and we lose something precious and beneficial.

Comment: @MarkAmery Calling the feelings of others unreasonable almost always pushes them away and makes it much less likely that you'll convince them of anything (not that this post is about that at all, but (a) those people may read this either way and (b) I doubt this mindset wouldn't extend to that). Perhaps this is the goal, or an acceptable side effect, but to me it makes more sense to instead (a) try to understand where other people are coming from or at least accept that they experience life differently and (b) focus on why moderation actions such as closing is important or necessary.

Comment: @Dukeling I don't see any coherent perspective from which these actions can be important and necessary and yet it's simultaneously reasonable to feel angry about them. Doing your proposal (b) *necessarily* casts the feelings of the angry people as unreasonable - or at least I can't imagine a way for it not to do so.

Comment: @MarkAmery It can be reasonable to be angry if you don't understand *why* some actions are important or necessary, or if you simply have different priorities (SO prioritizes building a repository of high-quality content - it's entirely reasonable to disagree about the importance of that, but this might mean there isn't a place for you here). Although when I point out the effects of calling the feelings of others unreasonable, my argument isn't that their feelings are reasonable as much as it is that we should reflect on what we say and how we say it to promote constructive dialogue.

Comment: @MarkAmery Have you ever had success using "you're being unreasonable" in an argument in real life? Or perhaps think back about a time when you were really angry about something and try to imagine how you'd have responded if someone told you you were being unreasonable. To me it seems highly unlikely to deescalate any situation. Implying something is vastly different than explicitly stating it (although, as mentioned above, I don't believe that explaining actions necessarily implies anyone who disagrees is unreasonable).

Comment: Re *'The meme that "SO is not welcoming" has gone on for way too long and is just utter tripe.'*: [April Wensel may not agree](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52) with you.

Comment: @PeterMortensen yep, I glanced over that post previously and my thoughts are twofold: 1. I'm glad someone has done something other than complain, she actually setup a site of her own so that's good. 2. I saw nothing wrong with the comment in that Tweet that she linked and a lot of that post I disagree with, to go into detail would be going way off-topic and would take time. To describe the site as '*“toxic, inhumane wasteland.”*' is quite honestly, rather hyperbolic. I'd associate those words with the cesspits of 4chan (certain parts of it?) and their ilk.

Comment: Let's remember that it can actually be painful to have your carefully crafted question closed as a duplicate, especially in the common situation where an expert can recognise it as a duplicate, but a beginner can't, because they don't have sufficient grasp of the concepts to see that the two questions are equivalent. Closing a beginner's question as a duplicate should always be done with a comment explaining why, unless it's absolutely obvious. It's important to try and avoid the subtle unstated implication of "you should have known this".

Comment: The process of dupes and holds on questions needs a major overhaul.  I have a question right now on hold, and it is NOTHING close to what he/she claims to be duplicate or (whatever reason he chose). I work for a large IT company in Tampa, where we are SO PAID CLIENTS... 
 - yet one moderator who may be arbitrarily closing or marking posts incorrectly is pushing us more and more towards re-thinking our subscriptions here.  I am sure SO would not be happy losing a 36 seat Enterprise client because one moderators incorrect "judgement" call. My 2 Cents. John

Comment: @JohnS. 1. You don't pay to use SO, so don't use that as a threat. 2. I doubt it was one moderator, it was probably four users that voted to close it. 3. IF you feel like you have the proof to back up your claims, create a meta post and request it to be opened. I looked through your question history and I couldn't find that closed question, care to help me out? Your comment reeks of entitlement.

Comment: Why was my comment prior to this one removed? I never said anything "unwelcoming" and I countered @JohnS.'s comments. (The crux of it being SO is not teams and his mentioning of mods ages without knowing is poor judgement and has nothing to do with anything).

Comment: @Script47, I am removing all my comments in this thread. It has gotten off topic, and somehow we ( you and I ) got off on the wrong foot. I am having issues with some moderators in your partner network, and my comment about age came in to play, because I am getting nowhere trying to discuss my grievances with them. I jumped on your thread because I was running out of places to be heard on this topic. That being said, I guess we will just work around this , or look into other options. Have a great day.

Comment: @JohnS. Don't worry, I don't take personal issue with anything you've said. If this is a real issue *and* you can back it up, make a post on meta.

Answer (score 27):

The [previous answer's OP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381432/1079354) lacks some 10K visibility into the post, in which I've taken a look at and could provide a slightly narrower answer.

Note:  I largely do agree with the points made previously, but there's impetus to take this on a case-by-case basis.

---

## Users don't come to Meta happy to talk about duplicate closures.

The default, blunt, broad and overreaching stance of a user coming to Meta in regards to their closed question isn't chiefly to hold a discussion; it's to prove that they're right and we're wrong about how we moderated their question.

This is only asserted by the statement made in the (now-deleted) Meta post.

> A moderator then closed the question within about 20 seconds based on a superficial resemblance this question. A silly argument ensued suggesting my answer is not worthy anyway because it only works for non-POSIX compliant versions of sed.

But you know what?  I am no expert in Bash (even if I play one on TV), but I can see that the similarities aren't *that* superficial.

[This is the OP's question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55220417/1079354)

[This is the proposed dupe.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

From what I can interpret...the questions are asking and covering similar ground.  This *may* be what the OP is hung up on, given that they emphatically believe that the question hasn't been asked here before, but to the untrained eye, I see this as having been asked before.

There *could* be a path to salvation here; if the OP decides to focus their efforts ***explicitly*** on indicating that they want to skip duplicate blocks, then that could be enough to reopen the question; otherwise, it reads too similar for a layman like myself to objectively say one way or another.

## There is (unironically) a duplicate answer for these Meta questions.

[What can I do if I believe that my question was wrongly marked as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253521/1079354) contains enough information in it that any OP who takes the time to peruse the document could actually understand that, *instead* of coming to Meta and believing that our decision was based on a superficial resemblance, they should take the time and effort to edit their question to completely disambiguate it from the supposed duplicate.

To this point:

> Sometimes it just feels bad for ruining the experience of a user visiting this great site. How could this situation be handled better?

It's important for you to identify and recognize that when someone's already at this stage - that is, they're essentially talking down to us and putting us in a position that makes us seem less competent than we actually are - their experience is *already* ruined.  Salvaging that isn't really going to happen, no matter how much effort you put into it.

The best thing we can do is guide them to the documentation we already have on situations like this.  If they choose to simply not follow the advice, no amount of talking to them would convince them to stay on this platform.

Comment: '*Users don't come to Meta happy to talk about duplicate closures.*' - +1 just for this line. The mere act of bringing something to the public scene can be seen as confrontational and then add in to the mix people's emotions and you're going to get some upset people.

Comment: I was involved in clarifying the question. Before some changes, they were way too close.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the alleged duplicate returns a _list of multiline text strings_; my question asked for the _head of the list of multiline text strings_ (or allows an assumption that the list has only one element). I can't for the life of me understand why this is confusing.

Comment: By the way, to people who still maintain this is a duplicate, the solution to it: `sed '0,/PATTERN1/d;/PATTERN2/Q'` - is a really useful sed oneliner. Unlike much sed, it's clear and readable, it's concise- and I have needed a solution to this problem (lines between 2 patterns exclusive) so many times. But my code doesn't solve the problem at the linked question. So where was I supposed to put it? I spent a good 15 mins and couldn't find anywhere. If I follow through the logic of this hardline "no dupes" policy, it would mean that I shouldn't share my code. Is that really where we want to be?

Comment: @AlexHarvey:  It's important that you make that assertion in your question.  It's clearer *now*, but for those laymen who aren't as expert in sed as you are, explaining the difference requires patience.  We're not out to slight you or doubt you or anything like that.

Comment: I am not sure how I might include that information in the question. I did try a few times, and each time I deleted my amended text again because the text to justify the question's existence was taking up more space than the question itself and it was just distracting. What concerns me is just how much good information must have been lost as a result of the Meta community's prevailing stance on aggressively closing questions "duplicates" even when they are merely similar. I have no doubt it is to the detriment of the site.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55160356/3787051) is how I do it when I see questions that are quite similar but I can judge that closing as dupe isn't going to help the person who needs assistance. Note I linked to the similar question, and refrained from repeating myself in the explanation. The end result is better for me; better for the asker; better for the Puppet community; and better all round.

Answer (score 16):

It strikes me that while we are correctly determining that some askers are in too much of a hurry to get an answer, it's also true that those of us attempting to answer questions can be in too much of a hurry as well.

It is reasonable to expect all members to take a few minutes of close inspection and research. This applies to the person posting, and the person answering.

A personal example of each from the last week:

1. Before asking a particular question, I looked for dupes. In my efforts, I found what could appear to be a dupe, but I didn't understand the answer. So, when I posted my question, I took the time to refer to that possible dupe, and made it clear that it didn't answer my question sufficiently. As a result, I was treated by the answerer with graciousness.
2. On the flip side, as one who was answering a question, I answered what looked like a dupe, but on closer inspection, realized that it was better to call it "related." So I referred to the related post, and also did my best to answer the question.

Final Thoughts:

1. It is reasonable to expect that both sides should look closely at possible dupes before writing.
2. One more thought, based on something I saw here in this thread: Perhaps we should all agree that the expression of one's feelings has no place here. This venue is for intellectual discourse only.

Answer (score 11):

**Closed as duplicate is basically the *least* insulting close reason possible (with the possible exception of 'too broad'); it also is one which provides answers**

As such I'm not sure what you *can* do, short of not closing as duplicate, which is for obvious reasons not a problem.

One possible change could be changing the term 'closed' that appears on duplicate posts and just calling them duplicates (whilst still functionally closing them). However whether this cosmetic change is worth the development time, or even would placate these users, is an open question

Answer (score 2):

@Inian, I appreciate that you are considerate enough to think about the feelings of others. That sets you clearly apart from many others here.

In this instance, I had put a lot of effort into that question, and it can be seen even in the [first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b1a1ff14-97bc-4f51-8cbc-4e01f072f132/view-source) that I had noted explicitly, and clearly, that:

> Despite many similar questions, including a more complicated variant that has been asked repeatedly where the patterns may recur, I don't think this exact question has been asked before.

If you had read that, you should have known:

- I had spent a lot of time looking at "many similar questions" and yet as a 5,000+ rep user, I had formed a view that the question had not been asked before.
- I already had explained why my question was different, namely, because the related questions allowed for "the patterns to recur".

The bit that concerns me is that despite me being a 5,000+ rep user, and despite me rarely asking questions at the site, and despite having been a developer for 20 years, you immediately dismissed what I'd said and ruled I was wrong. You did it without testing my code too. Because if you'd [done that](https://gist.github.com/alexharv074/2f5ed774248277d06bf6f05325206d51#file-gistfile1-txt-L55-L63), you would have realised you were simply wrong.

Of course, it is disheartening. When you put effort in as a volunteer to improving the site, and someone then deletes your effort after a 30 second review, you feel bad. Anyone will feel bad.

So, the answer to your question ought to be this:

If someone has obviously put a lot of effort into a question, as I had- i.e. if the writing is clear, if it provides expected inputs and outputs, if it is formatted well, if there is evidence of research- then:

*Make sure you put the same amount of effort in before deciding to "dupe-hammer" it*.

**IN ADDITION:** I also would like to clarify that the OP's post conveys an incorrect impression that I lost my temper and threatened to quit Stack Overflow over this dupe-hammer issue. That never happened. All that did happen is I deleted my Meta post again after receiving no help, no constructive feedback, and 7 downvotes.

Comment: '*I had put a lot of effort into that question, and it can be seen even in the first version that I had noted explicitly, and clearly, that:*[...]' - If you venture into the PHP tag, you'll see many a questions with notices like this but actual examples of what questions they looked through and ***why*** it isn't a duplicate. '*I had spent a lot of time looking at "many similar questions" and yet as a 5,000+ rep user*' - Reputation does not indicate how right or wrong a person can be, a 20K user can post and dupe for it to be closed too, doesn't make it any less right.

Comment: '*When you put effort in as a volunteer to improving the site, and someone then deletes your effort after a 30 second review, you feel bad.*' - Your question wasn't deleted, it was marked as dupe and the difference is important, they're not the same and should be confused. Anecdotally, I was suspended by mistake (a much bigger deal than a closed question) and I took it to meta and thankfully, it was resolved, but the point is, be clear and be factual.

Comment: Are you still claiming that the questions are duplicates despite unit tests proving otherwise?

Comment: _The bit that concerns me is that despite me being a 5,000+ rep user, and despite me rarely asking questions at the site, and despite having been a developer for 20 years_ How is this relevant in any way?

Comment: _and someone then deletes your effort after a 30 second review_ No one "deleted your effort" (well, you did at a point). You have no idea how long the closer spent before closing, nor how long do they need to evaluate a post. Do not dismiss _their_ effort and experience.

Comment: I guess we all make mistakes from time to time and sometimes we just disagree. The key is not to take it personal and not to overreact. In the end, we are all on the same side - making a great Q&A site. It does not help our cause, if accusations are thrown around and users get antagonized (neither you nor Inian).

Comment: Thanks @jpp. Yes I'll go back to answering questions in the main site. Definitely more fun. :)

Comment: **Mod Note**: Can we keep the comments en pointe? No need to have back and forth slinging matches. Meta can be very unwelcoming at times, it's a fair call.

Answer (score -11):

Hmm. Maybe we need to use :-) more around here? No, seriously. It's hard to get intent from text alone, but tossing a simple smiley on it can change the tone of a comment to something drastically more positive, or so I've noticed.

Comment: I'm really debating if I should upvote or downvote this answer, I want to upvote it because the direct tone of StackOverflow comments is a common confusion factor, but the emoji symbol is going to distract people who like stackoverflow for its direct communication of problem solving, its really hard for me to decide. :-)

Comment: I see your point but I disagree with it.  Feigning politeness in the face of an adversarial position isn't as constructive as keeping calm and working to calm the other person down.

Answer (score -16):

**Maybe the answer is to not mark every duplicate question as duplicate if it is not an exact duplicate**

I just had [a question marked as duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55237093/681045), I don't really understand the answer completely in the original answer that was linked. This was very bad user experience and felt quite unwelcoming. Will I make a SO post next time? Maybe not, because it is rarely any idea nowadays since many posts just get locked like mine and linked to another.

I am no MongoDB expert and even if the moderator was kind enough to give a solution in the comment (that I haven't been able to make it work for my case). I would want other kind souls to perhaps also give me some feedback instead of just one moderator.

Is it really that bad that we have many examples of basically the same thing showing how it's done in different angles? I don't think so, the more examples the merrier. For me, it doesn't really matter if I am the wrongdoer (which I most likely am) I still have the same issue and it is not resolved, I did not recieve the help I was expecting to get from this site.

Comment: This is depressing. You miss the entire point of SO and duplicates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ would probably make for good reading. There's some tricky balances to manage here. In this particular case, the dupe target answer seemed to my non-expert examination to be complete enough to be useful but simple enough to be workable. So it's a little tough to see what kind of answer you could have gotten that would have still been useful to anyone else without just being a lousy rewrite of that.

Comment: @nathanTuggy maybe in this particular case, yes. Maybe it's just me that is stupid but I still cannot solve my issue. This is not really the first time I've felt like this and that also comes down to viewing other questions that me myself have not asked. Too often it's just marked as a duplicate and the duplicate answer is not enough to solve the issue at hand.

I agree with the post Jeff made though.

Comment: @PasserBy You may think so, but I do not really agree with the premise of having duplicates unless they really are pretty much an exact duplicate. What is wrong with that?

Comment: You contradict yourself: _"Maybe the answer is to not mark every duplicate question as duplicate if they are well structured and it is a good defined question."_

Comment: @PasserBy Sorry for my inperfect english, but I assume you understand the point I am trying to convey, do you not?

Comment: No, I don't, You are saying closing as dupe shouldn't be used if the question is well-written. Then you say it should be if it is a dupe.

Comment: **Is it really that bad that we have many examples of basically the same thing showing how it's done in different angles?** It's indeed not bad to have many examples of the same thing, that's exactly why the question isn't deleted, but closed. It's not gone. We do want to keep all answers together though, so more examples that solve the issue can be posted as answers within the linked question. (1/2)

Comment: **Now, to solve your issue**, you'll have to read the answers and the linked documentation. Not having time to do so isn't an issue we can solve. After that, there are three outcomes (1) You understand everything, and the answers are helpful. (2) You don't understand something, and you can ask a new, separate, question asking for clarification what X means, quoting the original material. (3) You understand the matter, but it doesn't answer your question. Now you can edit your question to clarify why the duplicate doesn't answer your question, and vote to reopen it. (2/2)

Comment: @PasserBy Well what I am saying is that my question isn't an exact duplicate and therefore should not have been closed. Sure, the original answer most likely will help me a lot to achieve a solution to my issue but it seems that I still is in a need of an example on how to solve my particular case in order to even understand how the functionality works.

Comment: @g00glen00b Yes I can do all that, or I can ask another community for help which is most likely what I will do..

Comment: That aside, you still miss the point of SO. SO isn't a help desk, forum or chat room. We don't do personalized step-by-step troubleshooting. You should indeed seek something else if that is your expectation.

Comment: I know that, Passer By. I've been on SO for many years and both answering and asking questions. But years ago it wasn't this elitist as it is today. Judging from your and others attitude, it isn't likely to change anytime soon either.

Comment: @g00glen00b I present an alternate answer to this question and it gets downvoted to oblivion because it's impopular and goes against the current narrative of the people most engaged on this site. This comment thread is a great example. Sure I can taken my time to write an essay to explain my reasoning better but is that really how it's supposed to be?

Comment: @Ms01 I don't think you have to write an essay. This appears to be a case of two people (you and the person who voted to close this) disagreeing with each other, and in such cases, people usually explain why they believe X (or not). So to answer your question, yes, I believe that explaining your reasoning is the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: "I don't really have the time to go through a lot of documentation right now so for me this was very bad user experience and felt quite unwelcoming." By saying this, are you implying that you would rather *wait for someone to come read and solve your problem for you even if it might take them longer than the time it would take you to go through the documentation?*

Comment: @Jerry No, that is not what I am implying. I just don't have time to search the entirety of mongodbs documentation website in search of a solution to my issue. I admit that it was poorly worded. I have went through the answer and the documentation linked (at least the majority of the parts) but I am still stuck.

Comment: @g00glen00b Yeah but in my last comment directed to you I was talking about my answer to this meta question. In practice, you have to write an essay if you want to get up votes and not misinterpreted. You will have to be quite good at the english language because otherwise you will be downvoted and people will be unfriendly.

Or do you really think my post to this meta question deserves 9 down votes?

Comment: @Ms01 I hope I wasn't unfriendly, because if I was, it wasn't intentional and then I would like to apologize. Additionally, be aware that downvotes on Meta have two meanings, first of all, they still measure quality (as on the main site), but additionally, they measure agreement. For example, I downvoted because you initially stated that you would prefer not marking questions as a duplicate if they're well asked. I disagreed with that, but I just noticed you changed your statement, and now I see no reason to disagree with it, so I've undone my downvote.

Comment: No you were very friendly and helpful @g00glen00b. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: I think there is a good point here about that what constitutes a duplicate isn't binary, and that there are real negative effects of being to far on either side on the scale of judgment. It's easy to focus solely on cleaning up here, a reminder not to throw out the baby with the bathwater is appreciated.

Comment: FYI I would remove the link to your question. Good way to lose rep and have it mass-downvoted. Luckily doesnt seem to have affected you but I have seen it done loads of times on meta (or mass upvoting if the meta community approves)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. If your question had been asked in one of my tags, I would have tried very hard to answer it, regardless of similarity to another one.