# Has SO ever asked professional female developers about what they think of SO?

Tags: discussion, survey, gender

I just finished looking through the 2019 Developer Survey and I was disturbed by how much of the focus was on gender. Up front are 11 questions in the demographics section with gender as a focus or stratification option, and several more in the other sections. The take homes:

- Women suffer from feelings of inferiority (Feelings of Competence By Gender)
- Women don't feel as welcome on here (Do Developers Consider Themselves Part of the Stack Overflow Community?)
- Women have more feelings overall (Developers' Perspectives By Gender)

I know you are getting these answers from the surveys, but I am quite surprised at the narrative that is being implicitly built off those answers.

**Personal Anecdote:**

As a professional female developer, my biggest gender-related challenge at work is being taken seriously. It's not even a big problem since I work with awesome people and my work is appreciated. But it does come up, most often with the topic of how I express work-appropriate emotions such as frustration, irritation, and anger. I don't express them in the same way my male colleagues do and so sometimes it makes my co-workers uncomfortable and they act weird.

This reaction itself can be irritating. However, I figure I'm teaching them how to work with someone different than themselves, and I know it's not my problem if they don't like how my face looks when I'm frustrated. They can deal with it.

**How this relates to the survey:**

I think this survey could help reinforce the problem I've just described. My impression while reading it was that, once again, women are the "other". This survey and its takeaways re-highlight what tender little flowers we are that get our feelings hurt all the time. This isn't true. The whole problem is that people communicate differently and that one type of communication has been prioritized in programming for a long time.

The only question that got close to this problem was "Developers' Perspectives By Gender" and yet the word choices used came across as somewhat immature, suggesting younger or newer users. To me, it is immature (in its strictest definition - someone who hasn't had a lot of life experience yet) to assume rudeness of someone where directness was intended. Again this goes both ways - the way I express frustration about code not working is also not an indication of mental instability or weakness.

**My actual question:**

What, if anything, has SO done to reach out to professional female developers with experience? I would be interested to know what other women who use the site, and have 5+ years in the industry, think would be helpful towards this site's clear aim to be more welcoming to women. I don't need it to be any different - but someone, somewhere, obviously thinks there is a problem. If SO is going to try to "fix" this problem I would prefer they do it in such a way that doesn't push a really unhelpful narrative.

Comment: The best way to be more welcoming to women is to not specifically be more welcoming to women but to be equally welcoming to everyone.

Comment: I'm not quite following your thoughts about the survey. Do you have a problem with the questions themselves, [so]'s interpretation of the answers, the answers themselves (i.e. the state of the world), how others might interpret the answers, or something else?

Comment: @Dukeling thanks for asking. I could have been more clear. My problem is with the presentation and interpretation. When I answered the questions, I didn't know *a priori* that my answer for gender would be used for stratification of other answers. The decision to pull women out separately and present it to the world helps reinforce a refrain about women in the workplace that I have found, in my work experience, makes my life harder. I guess I would have preferred that the SO staff keep the demographic binning to themselves and use it internally to guide their business decisions.

Comment: Or, barring that, I wanted some reassurance that they have done something to reach out to other women working in the field to help guide these kinds of decisions. A lot of the discussion about this topic (as well as the bizarre conversations on this very thread) to me seem very *ad hoc*, emotionally-driven, and designed by one group for the benefit of another, without including that target group's input. I wanted to know I was wrong. It seems I am at least partially wrong if SO is interviewing women as `Shog9` says, which is something. And helpful to know.

Comment: I actually wonder if they even looked at [2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au1bU.png) VS [2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBojt.png). Why so much focus on women and minorities if the entire community feels much less welcomed since the Welcome Wagon?

Comment: Thank you for posting this.  It's always nice to hear from someone in the *actual group* being discussed, rather than the usual virtue-signaling folks that *think* they know what's good for some other group.

Comment: A data point to consider: [Julia Silge](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5468471/julia-silge) worked on the survey results

Comment: I'd like to see the demographics on the up-voters and down-voters on this question and the related answers. And thank you for the post.

Comment: "most often with the topic of how I express work-appropriate emotions such as frustration, irritation, and anger. **I don't express them in the same way my male colleagues do and so sometimes it makes my co-workers uncomfortable and they act weird.**"  Can you explain what you mean by this?  I'm fortunate enough to work with quite a few software engineer women, none of them appear to express such work appropriate emotions in an alien way.

Comment: "Be welcoming to everyone" sounds nice...but "everyone" hasn't been un-welcomed. Why would put resources into fixing an issue for everyone, when everyone doesn't have an issue? 

You wouldn't treat everyone for an illness if only people named Jill were sick, right? It would be nice to shoot for the goal of "everyone being healthy" but when there's a systematic issue that is targeted, the treatment needs to be targeted.

Comment: @BirdieGolden But being nice to someone is a continuous process. (admittedly you only 'welcome' someone once)

Comment: I should add that while SO has been toxic for women for a long time, it's unfortunately becoming toxic for everyone of late, which is really unfortunate because this has been a very solid community for a long time.

Comment: @KevinPanko while Julia, by all appearances, belongs in the target demographics, one individual does not amount to a consensus over a large group of humans.

Comment: This post is a perfect encapsulation of the issue. I'm a avid meta user, but some of the comments on here make it perfectly clear that we are divided as a community and that meta is getting yet more combative still, over everything these days. Why?

Comment: @Magisch because we are forced to take a stance on issues we believe we shouldn't take a stance into. Also, there conversation is way too emotionally loaded. Check out the announcement of changes to the HNQ. There wasn't any whiff of negativity. Instead check out the welcoming thingy. One of them was something that the community wanted addressed, the other thing wasn't something we considered a bug but a feature.

Comment: @Gimby Your comment is very much like #alllivesmatter, you're technically correct, but someone is raising an issue that needs addressing. What you are saying is women shouldn't get special treatment (because everyone is equal) however the current system supposedly does treat everyone equally, and is not working, hence the issue was raised. At this point, your comment risks coming across as "nothing further needs to be done to remedy the issue you've raised".

Comment: Is the problem that women are unhappy, or that women are being described as unhappy?

Comment: @HFBrowning I wanted to say that I really appreciated this post, and the idea as a whole that it drives forward. I hope I didn't misinterpret your intent in [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382767/2642059). Thank you for being such an important part of "us."

Comment: @opa this is hard for me to answer, since *I* think I'm expressing myself completely normally :) I think the best answer is that I am more expressive overall than a lot of my colleagues, so if they happen to stop by when I'm puzzling over something they might be initially met with a furrowed brow and a frown. I do try to turn it around to something friendly and welcoming as quick as I can, but it's also just kind of who I am to smile a lot if I'm happy, and to actually frown if something seems wrong or off. I've been called out for it, and it's been hinted I'm too emotional.

Comment: From the answers it seems like StackOverflow so far did some interviews but not too many and probably could get a more complete picture by asking more. Also they did not yet publish any summary results of interviews of professional female developers. Questioning the communication culture and being more open and kind seems to be the right direction with benefits for everyone (including for example those men who also communicate differently from the majority of the current user base).

Comment: @HFBrowning I could be wrong, but to me it sounds like your explanation as answer to opa's comment is not really bound to a gender. I know male programmers who do that as well

Comment: @lucidbrot I don't believe my behavior is either. However, I have had pretty gendered interactions about it - I'm skeptical a man would be called "emotional" or "snippy" for doing what I do. This is exactly my point :) But this part of my post (my personal experiences) isn't something I want to discuss further (up until this point has been fine) only because a further back and forth about it is bound to become pretty off topic.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I wanted to comment on this:

> The whole problem is that people communicate differently and that one type of communication has been prioritized in programming for a long time.

I don't know if that's the *whole* problem - these situations tend to involve a *lot* of distinct problems and folks just pick the ones that they feel they can discuss comfortably. But... It is definitely A Problem.

The same factors that make someone like me more comfortable on a SO-style Q&A site than in, say, Slack... Are undoubtedly making a lot of the folks who find themselves drawn to Slack supremely uncomfortable on SO. But why is this a problem? Let's go [back to Stack Overflow's charter](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/04/16/stackoverflowcom/)...

> Programmers seem to have stopped reading books. The market for books on programming topics is miniscule compared to the number of working programmers.
>
> Instead, they happily program away, using trial-and-error. When they can’t figure something out, they type a question into Google.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Jeff Atwood and I decided to do something about it. We’re starting to build a programming Q&A site that’s free. Free to ask questions, free to answer questions, free to read, free to index *[...]*

It's easy to forget, but that's *still our goal here* - to facilitate the transmission of good, useful information on programming. But right now, that only happens when the folks with that information are comfortable using SO-style Q&A. It doesn't happen when that information is trapped away in Slack, or in Twitter DMs, or SnapChat stories or whatever kids today are comfortable using. That information is *effectively lost.* And with it, the hope of saving all those folks typing programming questions into Google from a fate worse than reading books...

So yeah. We need to learn to communicate differently. *I* need to learn to communicate differently. And then we need tools to help other folks do so more easily, and ideally without being forced to use Slack until their eyes bleed from all the emojis.

But, you ask, enough about Shog and his problems with Slack - what do *women* say about Stack Overflow?

### Talking to women about SO

Anecdotally, we've been hearing for years that *some* women feel uncomfortable participating on Stack Overflow... Or in the field of programming *in general*. And it's not a great leap to assume that the two are probably related in some way. Heck, **over three years ago now**, [Yvette kicked off a fairly massive discussion about this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309908/declining-numbers-of-women-in-programming-what-can-so-do-to-help) - I'll leave you to read that at your leisure, but here's a particularly relevant bit:

> When there is an even mix of men and women it is very different than when I am acutely aware of the lack of women, and am usually the only woman in all my sets of interactions on most days on SO. And I do become very defensive when I know there's a bunch of men and if I don't communicate well and then there's discussion, it quickly leads to me being very defensive. Is this your fault? No. Is it my fault, but I'm also doing my best, as it is really difficult. I'm making this appeal, so that the tiniest changes can be made to ease the way for women to come into the field and succeed.

This is something we've heard echoed over and over again as we've talked to women who *want* to participate on SO, but don't: they feel alone, surrounded by people who don't speak the same way, don't react the same way, don't have the same expectations... It's stressful and intimidating in a way that *isn't as true for men*.

We've conducted a bunch of these interviews over the past year to try to better guide efforts like this survey; we'll probably do a lot more before we're through. We've talked to recent grads, experienced professionals, self-taught and lots of variety in between. The population of *people who don't participate on SO* is enormous; there are no doubt countless reasons, and many of them aren't things we can or should address - but it is our mission to identify the problems that we *can and should* be fixing.

### Not all women

I think it's safe to say that *no one* involved with the survey wanted to do anything to make women reading it feel patronized or "othered", or to imply that the experience on Stack Overflow is *the same for all women*. That doesn't negate *your* feelings upon reading it of course - but consider this: **one value of a survey like this is to illustrate just how diverse the opinions and experiences are *even within similar groups*.**

It is, frankly, dispiriting at times to read some of the results from these surveys. But there is hope too: through exercises like this we may become better informed about the needs and desires of the folks using these sites, and once again strive for that noble goal laid out so many years ago...

Comment: I need to digest your answer a bit (thanks for posting) but I wanted to say, first, that I laughed about your first point. You're totally correct. As I was editing my question's format I noticed that I had hyperbolized the heck out of my statement there, but wasn't bothered enough to fix it.

Comment: The focus on women and minorities is, IMO, distracting. The far bigger problem is that Meta & the SO culture is toxic and hostile in a way that makes everyone feel unwelcome. I am a white, male, senior developer and I never in my life encountered a nastier online forum than SO Meta. And I've been an open source developer for years. This place reminds me of Usenet in the 1990s. I expect that women/minorities are misinterpreting general nastiness as something racist or sexist, when it probably mostly is not.

Comment: Can I add that the world's a strange place? We still have recognised countries (by the UN) where they've only just got the idea that a "woman" can actually drive a motor vehicle. It's saddening. SO does its bits towards equality - but we must recognise SO can't shape the world -- but it tries its best and I've seen it trying to. (just a mod on the site - not official).

Comment: @JonClements, that would be more relevant if SO was dominated by men from those countries, rather than men from the United States and other western countries.

Comment: @AlexHarvey '*[...] and I never in my life encountered a nastier online forum than SO Meta.*' - First of all, that statement is unbelievably hyperbolic and within it is one of the reasons why so many new users get a bad reception, SO is ***not*** a forum, it is a Q&A site, a subtle but distinct difference. To address your quite frankly, ridiculous statement, you've turned to meta for many issues which may or may not have been resolved, however, after that, were you trolled? Doxxed? Insulted (I mean, offensively, not just disagreement)?

Comment: I highly doubt it, but, the aforementioned things are what happens on other forums. Can we stop flogging the dead horse in regards to making it seem as though SO is the most noninclusive place on the internet and that we've, by nature of our behaviour have made it such. This non-inclusivity drivel is just people hurt at the fact that their questions get closed because rules are enforced.

Comment: Honestly, people should try to create a platform similar to SO while not enforcing the rules that SO has and see how that turns out. The amount of crap you'd have wade through to find a decent question or answer would be unintelligible.

Comment: @Script47 My impression is that such a concept for a platform has been tried over and over without reaching a wide audience, which kind of speaks for itself.

Comment: @E_net4 yes and, no platform, no matter how conscious they are regarding inclusivity, will reach everyone and they'll always be criticism in one form or another. It goes back to the age old adage '*Damned if you do, and damned if you don't.*' (You can't please everyone).

Comment: @Script47, you write (to others in this thread), "This non-inclusivity drivel is just people hurt at the fact that their questions get closed because rules are enforced"..."The amount of crap you'd have wade through to find a decent question or answer would be unintelligible". Do you think you could be any more dismissive? It is not surprising that you can't understand why others perceive an issue with inclusiveness.

Comment: *I* never in my life encountered a nastier online forum than SO Meta. SO Meta is especially non-inclusive and resembles an Old Boys' club. What's more, many are open about wanting to keep it this way. Meta is for *everyone*.

Comment: @AlexHarvey You don't seem to understand, if you come out with statements to provoke, as you have done several times, expect to get dismissed. Also, what did I say wrong? IF another platform was created and they did NOT enforce rules like SO then you WOULD be wading through crap, that is FACT. Look through the queues that get handled by the curators and see the sort of stuff that gets closed, deleted, handled and see how "bad" it is, the only reason *you* don't see it is because it gets handled by people who care about quality.

Comment: As for the my opinion of it being drivel, yes, I do believe it to be, that doesn't dismiss your opinion, I'm merely stating mine. On the other hand, don't misunderstand me, IF a user IS being racist, sexists or, any other '*ism*' then absolutely, they ***should*** be dealt with, other than that, I don't think much more can be done. I'm not sure what else could be done for this? You can't cherry pick my comments and put them together, they were spanned across three separate comments for two reasons: the five minute lock and the fact that they were different from the previous comments topic.

Comment: Again: '*It is not surprising that you can't understand why others perceive an issue with inclusiveness.*' - You constantly throw accusations around based on assumptions when you clearly took two *different* comments out of context. In context, there is absolutely nothing wrong with them. As for *your opinion* regarding my understanding, let me make it easier for you: ***Everyone*** should follow the sites rules, that includes the be-nice policy. The reason why I feel this won't help is that I don't see what else could be done. Rules won't stop people who want to be racists or sexist.

Comment: The specific debate about how to get more women into tech isn't new and I believe others have already come to the conclusion that lack of female role models is one key reason. That's what I'm sensing between the lines here too, both in the OP's post and in that quoted discussion.

Comment: @Lundin that leaves me to wonder why there are no female role models on SO. I know there are females, but I don't consider any of them to be a role model. But that might just be me being an educated white straight male from a western European country, the most privileged as they come. I know the crap people get when they use a "female" avatar, as I wrote in my answer, so it takes some tough skin to step up and be that role model if one should desire that.

Comment: @Luuklag Ironically, 4 years later after that post by Yvette, she is now a diamond mod with 20k+ rep. So there you go.

Comment: @Lundin, agreed. However I tend to find some controversy around her as well. Could be that that goes with the diamond badge but usually role models should be of bespoke behaviour. Nothing against Yvette though.

Comment: What if we don't ask questions about gender/race/ethnicity on future surveys and just stick to programming topics?

Comment: Pretending there's no issue with diversity in this field isn't going to make the issue go away. You'll find people denying it even when presented with statistics so I think SO absolutely should continue to include those questions.

Comment: I haven't read my linked question in a looong time and the quoted section in your answer made me feel good. Maybe I wasn't so off base for posting it. When I wrote that question I remember feeling immense pressure in the comments and ended up getting cranky in my replies. The pile on was overwhelming. We've come a looong way as a site and community. I feel happy with our progress. We're battling a lot of deeply entrenched societal issues, problems that are highlighted within the programming community and hence the site. I am not giving up. I stand here to help people who feel marginalised.

Comment: @jpp "...SO Meta is especially non-inclusive and resembles an Old Boys' club..." I also don't feel very comfortable on SO Meta at times and I'm not a woman. But I guess it comes down to what one can do about it? Cultural changes sometimes take decades.

Comment: @TimothyPulliam "What if we don't ask questions about gender/race/ethnicity on future surveys and just stick to programming topics?" You mean potential problems might just vanish if we would avoid talking about them? Tried and tested strategy, I'll admit that.

Comment: @Trilarion, For a start, moderators can help by accepting flags on well-received but unwelcoming posts / comments, e.g. "If you can't take constructive criticism, you shouldn't be on the Internet" is a widely appreciated comment here on Meta. But there's a stark difference between making a disinterested, helpful suggestion, e.g. "Many users comment to help you improve your post", and making *unnecessary value judgments* on who should be on SO or "the internet". These outwardly innocuous but snarky comments have no place on a Q&A platform.

Comment: I'm [on the record](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381212/is-the-intensity-of-meta-working-in-our-favor-or-to-our-detriment) as thinking that meta is quite hostile and it's a real shame, because all of that hostility is discouraging people from learning more about the site. Be it fatigue or failing tools or whatever, something has to give in the long run, we can't keep this level hostility up forever. I don't think it's particularly snarky comments but opening meta to find a different post complaining about SE's efforts every day is getting annoying and wearing me out

Comment: @jpp "These outwardly innocuous but snarky comments have no place on a Q&A platform." Fully agreed. Some people will try to denounce it as political correctness obsession though. Maybe someone could invent an automatic snarkiness detector to help fight snarky comments more effectively? On the other hand, I often reply to snarky comment with snarky comments on my own. I know that doesn't help anyone and solves nothing, but it feels really good. Maybe I should not do it anymore.

Comment: And not asking about demographics and issues is a ridiculous red herring. All that does is make the data set look less depressing, but the depressing reality is still right there. Not talking about a problem does not make it go away, it makes it fester. We've "not talked" about gender representation for years on here, to the point of frequently reacting to posts like yvette's with hostility and derision, and evidently that has not solved anything and if nothing else just made things worse.

Comment: This conversation and the surrounding efforts need to happen, and we can either help shape and inform them or take every single acknowledgement of an issue as a personal slight and get hung up in an all or nothing "curation or welcomingness" narrative. I expect better from us. We're all problem solvers, so lets work on solving the problem that a large chunk of developers won't feel comfortable participating here, and lets do it without harming curation efforts. Doom & gloom and complaining about political correctness doesn't help and won't make

Comment: SE shelve their efforts, it just marks the people complaining about it as hyperbolic and not worth listening to to those making the decisions.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Three comments later, the site makes your point for you.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I believe you are talking about my comment? If so, if someone disagrees with a premise, are they automatically being unwelcoming, nasty, or hostile? If that's the case then we are definitely treading on some thin ice here. Or, would you like to point out where I was nasty in my comment?

Comment: @Script47 If you find yourself in a hole, stop digging.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Advice duly noted, now, back to my question, what is wrong with my comment? It's humorous how you think I have any issues with what I've stated and how you think I'm "in a hole". I stand by what I said. In the future, actually *try* rebut what I said.

Comment: @Script47 I think David point was to ignore him and what he represents.

Comment: @Braiam Nah, that there's no point in rebutting a self-rebutting comment.

Comment: @Script47, I'll have a go at rebuttal. You seem to imply in that comment that because I turned to Meta for help a few times, I should be grateful that I wasn't "trolled", "doxxed", or insulted _offensively_ - don't you think that's setting the bar for decency very low? Also, I love the idea that I should distinguish Meta's ordinary insults from the "offensive" ones that you are imagining that occur elsewhere. And the punchline is that your comment, at this time, is upvoted an incredible 44 times.

Comment: @AlexHarvey that's absolutely not what I meant, you've clearly misunderstood the comment. *You* said '*[...] and I never in my life encountered a nastier online forum than SO Meta.*' and I was simply explaining how on other forums that is the outcome, the only thing that happens here is down-votes or closing which are not comparable with the others. I have stated and will continue to state, if you use the site, then you need to use it inline with the be-nice policy. (Meta) SO is made out as some ungodly demon for some unfathomable reason. Are we saying all critique is now "bad"?

Comment: Fair enough @Script47. And where are these nastier forums that you've been to. The Dark Web?

Comment: @AlexHarvey because is true. The fact is that there are nastier online communities (just take any *chan). If you believe that down votes are nasty, you are misunderstanding their purpose.

Comment: Ok, @Braiam, so it's 4chan where I can find myself a real dose of hostility is it? True, I haven't hung out there.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I see you aren't acquainted with Reddit or 4chan? Hell, even the smaller web forums that I used to use previously had issues like that. You don't need to look to the dark web to find people who are just bad. My main point is, the insults that SO gets tarred with are unbelievably unfair.

Comment: Ok, @Script47, it seems like I've led a sheltered life and only hung out in places like GitHub, technical Slack communities, Wikipedia, politics forums, Facebook groups, etc. Compared to all those, Meta is the most hostile.

Comment: @AlexHarvey You are conflating hostility with critique. A person who's never been grilled by professionals or learned hobbyist will feel as though they are being treated unfairly, that is, until they see that everyone is critiqued in the same way.

Comment: And @Script47, you believe that because everyone is treated equally badly, it's actually ok.

Comment: @AlexHarvey no! Stop drawing assumptions where they don't exist. Where I differ is that I don't believe criticism is intrinsically "bad". I don't take it personally and I use it to learn and grow as a developer and more importantly, a person. Again, you are conflating criticism with nastiness.

Comment: I don't know, before-the-flood 4chan /b/ (I was an oldchap, no idea how it is now) was much more collaborative and fun than I've ever seen Meta, and its active users weren't all tendentious sea lions.

Comment: @Script47, The issue is nastiness is subjective. A stream of swearing, although indefensible, is to me *less offensive* than a [snarky answer which says that anyone who can't take positive criticism shouldn't be on the internet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381432/9209546). Meta.SO is a Q&A site for SO users. Value judgments on who is or is not welcome on SO, the internet, or elsewhere are unwarranted. They are also unwelcoming when, as here, they clearly target or reference a particular poster. My flag on that post was declined with a weak custom reason.

Comment: @jpp I was not being snarky there at all. I was being dead serious and [I already addressed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381430/spurned-authors-deleting-their-questions-after-they-are-closed-as-duplicate/381432#comment678847_381432) the criticism regarding my wording choice in the comments chain and for that matter, [I addressed you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381430/spurned-authors-deleting-their-questions-after-they-are-closed-as-duplicate/381432#comment678939_381432) directly to which you never responded.

Comment: If you take critique as an insult, that's on you and that's the point I was making albeit somewhat bluntly. You can't expect to come onto this site and not get challenged, and if you do, take it as though you are being treated unfairly. You are being intellectually dishonest with yourself with that mindset.

Comment: @Script47, and the root of the problem is there. You are not aware that your snarkiness is snark, even if 99 out of 100 other people can tell.

Comment: @AlexHarvey your 99/100 needs a citation, I believe the overwhelming majority is agreeing with me as can be seen by the up-votes with that answer and I am fully aware of when I'm being snarky or insulting, though thanks for the assumption, once again.

Comment: @Script47 Here you go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealioning

Comment: @DavidEisenstat this is the issue, you'll throw buzzwords around and you won't back it up (yes, I can see the irony). I can throw that same thing back at you, you want to debate and claim that SO is unfriendly yet you don't want to accept that it is a minute number of incidents as compared with the massive number of people that have been helped or are being helped.

Comment: @Script47, I agree that you make a good point about the upvotes. I can't blame you, I guess, that you think that post is okay, considering all the upvotes. Bad behaviour has been normalised in this forum. I can tell you, though, that if you send that out in a public email in most places I ever worked, you'd be fired.

Comment: @AlexHarvey ***SO is not a forum and this difference is not negligible.*** You misinterpret the stringent rules and critique as a personal attack when it isn't. Bad behaviour has not been normalised, look at how mods clamp down on behaviour that goes opposite to the be-nice policy, see how quickly flags are handled and again, I would disagree with you, my answer ***in context*** is 100% fine. What you're claiming is that all the users, mods, and staff that frequent this site complicit in allowing bad behaviour? Could it be possible that a handful of users take things too personally?

Comment: No, @Script47, I don't want to "debate" how someone perceives Meta. That's the point. Also, this comment chain seems awfully forum-like to me. Maybe I should flag it.

Comment: @Script47, I must admit that I am somewhat amused that you are defending this forum/Q&A community distinction. Why is this relevant in a discussion about acceptable behaviour?

Comment: @Script47, For what it's worth, *many* of my Meta.SO flags (mostly successful) are for comments between +10 and +50 upvotes. Don't believe that upvotes somehow prove a comment or post is not unwelcoming.

Comment: @AlexHarvey because the Q&A aspect of this site ensures no nonsense or duplicates and that is sometimes perceived as being "unfriendly". So when people close, down-vote, people immediately believe they are being wronged. Not everything is on-topic. Forums are fundamentally different and much more free in what they accept.

Comment: @jpp I've never argued that up-votes determine friendliness, what I did say was that it generally indicates agreement, stop jumping around to things that suit you and address my contentions. Throwing these statements around just fogs the real discussions taking place.

Comment: @Script47, I am not convinced that Meta is truly a "Q&A community", but let's leave that alone. Where I do agree is people at this "site" clearly believe that it's important to cast (anonymous) judgement in the forum of up and downvotes on "questions" and "answers" and this "judgement" is a big part of why the forum is so unwelcoming.

Comment: @AlexHarvey there we have it. Your issue is with the core premise of this site, that is, closing and anonymous  down-voting. So my question to you is, should the whole site change to suit you? Why can't you fall into place with regards to how the system has ran and is being ran in the same way so many people before you have? People can masquerade this unwelcoming stuff however they want but the simple truth is this, it always tends to fall back to questions being closed or down-voted.

Comment: @Script47, I agree that it is a big part of it, yes, and certainly not all of it. And should the whole site change to please me? No. It should change to please [this guy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?_ga=2.27970292.996740895.1545528694-1783461704.1532701787).

Comment: @AlexHarvey changing the whole site is a tall order, and as you probably noted that blogpost ( and any conversation about it ) provokes fierce arguing and noted criticism at the best of times.

Comment: @AlexHarvey No, absolutely it shouldn't be changed to please one guy (who is now a former employee I believe). It should change (if it even need changing) to what the community can agree upon to be the next *right* step. No one, and I mean no one, from what I've seen with this "welcoming" debacle has ever argued that we should be less friendly, but they have augured that by enforcing quality you are not being unfriendly.

Comment: @Script47, it doesn't [look like](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jay-hanlon-11aaa377/) that guy is a former employee and in any case that blogpost is linked in the 2019 Developer Survey. I only read it for the first time today.

Comment: @AlexHarvey in any case, my point still stands, the *community* should work towards it, it shouldn't be dictated that everyone is "unwelcoming" and we need to fix that, no. First thing, you question, what parts of the site are found to be "unwelcoming" and why? If it is core parts like down-voting or closing then I'm sorry, unless SO plans to change how everything works, nothing will change (and for that matter, nothing should). You have to see it from the other side too, from the perspective of all the users who spent effort making this site what it is are now being told they are the cause...

Comment: of its decline. How do you think that would go down? People on the "welcoming" side (and it honestly is a divided camp) want empathy shown to them and their cause and to the new users but none is shown to the existing curators who pretty much helped make the site what it is today. Is that not "unfair" or "unfriendly" or "nasty"?

Comment: @Script47, I think that people _could_ learn that downvotes and close votes are almost always perceived negatively and they could and should be used sparingly and conservatively. Whereas at the moment, they are used often and aggressively.

Comment: @AlexHarvey again, that goes against what they are used for. Just because you *feel* that down-votes hurt you, should the sites goal of quality content curation be put on hold for YOU? Are you (or people who claim they are offended by down-votes or close-votes) also claiming that their will should trump everyone else's?

Comment: @AlexHarvey Close votes and downvotes (as well as reopen votes and upvotes) are there for quality control and are not personal. If someone takes them personally that is on them but voting is done on the _content_ not on the _user_.

Comment: I think this discussion is reaching the limit of the usefulness of comments. Perhaps it could be moved to chat?

Comment: @Script47, if I gave a damn personally about the downvotes I wouldn't still be here talking to you. I care more about things like, you know, writing quality software? Things that actually matter as opposed to meaningless anonymous DVs here in the land of Meta. BUT, they are offensive to nearly everyone, I think. Because I reckon everyone is human.

Comment: @AlexHarvey and there we go with your assumptions that if you get down-voted and don't take it offensively you aren't human? No, it means you've learnt the nature of this site. Let me shed a different light on this, how do you write quality software? You follow stringent rules and design patterns that are accepted that work. Sometimes those restrictions bite you in the backside but as an overall they work pretty well so that you take that bite and move on. Such is the case with (meta) SO, the quality answers you see and use are a direct result of people enforcing rules i.e. closeing and dvs.

Comment: Ok, yeah... I like having the discussion in public, but if it's just gonna be you two going back and forth all morning maybe take pity on my poor inbox and jump into [the tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)?

Answer (score 3):

In reading your question I'm seeing 3 main points:

1. There is a disturbing amount of gender focus
2. Women are treated as outsiders, or "the 'other'"
3. You'd prefer that SO didn't push this unhelpful narrative

And your question as I'm reading it is: What, if anything, do female industry veterans think should be done to improve the way SO welcomes women?

I should first clarify that I have no minority status, so I'm in no way qualified to answer to your actual question. *However* as a I member of the SO user base, I am an important part of the enactment of any solution that may be found here. And as a member of the SO user base I resonated very strongly with what I understood your 3 main points to be. I feel those points provide a framework for giving some direction on how to welcome women, minorities, and really everyone. I've taken the liberty of distilling these points into 2 suggestions for SO as a whole:

### 1. Be welcoming to all users

I think [Gimby's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382683/has-so-ever-asked-professional-female-developers-about-what-they-think-of-so?cb=1#comment686551_382683) sums this up nicely: "Be welcoming to everyone." Women, and all minorities, are part of the SO user base, they should be greeted with the same hospitality we show to everyone. They should *not* be treated as outsiders, as I cite in your point *2*. This throws slurs, and really derogatory comments toward anyone, right out. Such comments are an insult against the user base as a whole; because women and minorities are insiders, or part of "us". (As an aside I've been really proud of the SO leadership in driving this directive forward this year.)

### 2. Eliminate focus on gender, or minority status

I agree that the focus on explicit protection of females, and other minority groups, delivers the unhelpful narrative I cite in your point *3*. These groups are not presented as part of "us", not some "tender little flowers." I'm seeing 2 primary problems with this: 1<sup>st</sup> it plays what I've cited as your point *1* and it enforces fragmentation; the removal of women, and minorities, from us. 2<sup>nd</sup> It feeds the perception of reverse-racism where one group, minorities, get special treatment over "us." (I should clarify that there is no actual preferential treatment offered by SO, just an unhealthy focus.)

---

I'd like to close this post by stating how much I appreciate you driving forward what I feel is a healthy cultural perspective on women in the SO user base. I have a young daughter who is wonderful at math, and I'm really hoping to encourage her into Computer Science. I'd like to think that she'll be a part of SO, and the industry as a whole; and will be seen as part of "us."

Comment: '*I should first clarify that I have no minority status, so I'm in no way qualified to answer to your actual question.*' - This is a fundamental mistake in our thinking. Why is it assumed that you aren't qualified to answer a question because you aren't apart of a minority group? For example, and a rather extreme example, do I have to be a jew from the holocaust period to empathise with their situation and describe the feelings they must have felt? Absolutely not. It is precisely this sort of thinking that creates echo chambers.

Comment: I would like to emphasize that part of rationale for focusing on underrepresented groups is that a lack of presence of a particular group can act as a deterrent for getting more of that group to participate.  If I'm the only [insert protected class] in a setting, I'm not necessarily going to feel part of that community.  It's kinda Catch 22, which is why focusing on welcoming minority groups has some merit.  Obviously this shouldn't take all the bandwidth of development focus, but just leaving it alone can leave such groups marginalized and cut into the overall size of a userbase.

Comment: @ryanyuyu '*If I'm the only [insert protected class] in a setting, I'm not necessarily going to feel part of that community.*' - I guess this is the biggest contention I have. I believe, from my experiences, that SO is color blind / gender blind. You are merited for good content and punished (sounds too harsh?) for bad content. Period. Your "feeling" of being apart of this community is down to your contributions and I sincerely believe that. Anything else is your misjudging / assuming the motives of the community which is nothing but speculation.

Comment: @Script47 As a member of at least one minority group, I'd first like to confirm that SO is pretty good at being the meritocracy it claims to be.  But no one (and no system) is perfect, and it's naive to think that the users don't have unconscious bias based on cultural influence that leak into their interactions on SO.  SO users are still people.  Also, by selection bias I do feel like part of the community (else why would I be on meta).  This comment is for all the potential users who don't feel included.

Comment: I would like to upvote this 1000 times. SO does not have problem in particular with women or any other groups. Personal feelings cannot be denied, but that is all they are: personal feelings. Something bad happens, and people will jump to all kind of conclusions that it happened because of this or that, while in fact it did not. Emphasizing wrong problems - that women (or any other group) have more problems participating in SO, will only make that imaginary problem worse. I say imaginary because most of the developers I know that are reluctant to participate are experienced white males.

Comment: @Script47 I do agree with your comment, and have modified my statement somewhat. While I still see myself as not addressing the actual question, I do see myself as addressing the fundamental barriers to being more welcoming to women. And this should at least provide a foundation for any improvements deemed necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The things that I take away from this discussion is that:

- Participants that don't consider themselves to be (straight) white males <sup>[1]</sup>, the majority of the SO users, often feel misunderstood and alone.

Now there are a few things off my head that I can think about to "resolve" part of these issues, but am I in the right spot to voice my opinion being one of the majority? Usually one of the arguments in these debates is that we (straight white males) are not, but nonetheless I'll give it a go. I hope no one takes offence at my honest attempt to improve the SO life, and if you do please let me know. I'm more than willing to remove my post if needed.

**Feeling alone on SO**
For me feeling alone usually entails that I don't find people I identify with around me. If we generalize that to women on SO, I don't see them around that much, and heck I can't blame them. I saw the comments some of us leave on posts from profiles that go with a photograph of a woman as their avatar. It definitely ain't pretty.

I know we get rid of this garbage quickly, but in almost all cases the damage is already done and the comments are read by the one it was addressed to. And quite frankly I can't blame anyone for not wanting to show that they are a woman on SO. Unless we can find a way to stop anyone and everyone from leaving these comments, as unfortunately some can't find the decency to treat others with the respect they deserve, I don't expect women to make their profiles identifiable as such.

**Only the quality of your posts count**
Now I know there are people who think that it is only the quality of the things we post that should count, and I was stuck in that paradigm for a long time as well. But reading posts like this makes me think twice about that. Quality is in the eye of the beholder, and that is where things start to go downhill. What the concept of quality entails for me, one of the majority, might not be the same for anyone from a underrepresented group. I think we can all agree that a factual post with a correct answer is something we strive for. But quality is not only in the code in a post, but also in the way we write a post, in the way we communicate. And frankly no two groups communicate the same, hence we can easily feel misunderstood.

**Language**
There is an underlying assumption under what I covered so far, which is we all speak the same language. And yes we all speak English here on SO. But my, non-native, English isn't the same as your (non-)native English. And as I like to think my English is decent, there are others that struggle a bit more, and we can often feel misunderstood simply by this fact.

**Getting yourself out there** 
Now I could simply shout that everyone that doesn't identify themselves as a straight white male should let themselves be found as what they identify. Which is easy for me to say as part of the majority group. I think we should strive for a SO where this can happen, but for now I'm at a loss. We want people to not feel lonely, but we can't really provide the safe haven in which people can show who they really are and let others know that they are not alone.

---

<sup>[1]: <sub>Lets not generalise into women only, but lets take into account all  groups under-represented on SO</sub></sup>

Comment: "...What the concept of quality entails for me, one of the majority, might not be the same for anyone from a underrepresented group.... but we can't really provide the safe haven" But we could, I guess, kind of create a "white-male SO" (the existing one) and a "everything else safe haven SO". That may be one potential solution if you already say that quality in in the eye of the beholder. The other way is to try to become more inclusive, which is what I think SO currently tries but the inertia/resistance is rather big. Such changes probably take some time and lots of effort.

Comment: @Trilarion I'm genuinely baffled by what you said, what does "white-male SO" even mean? As for the "resistance", I don't think anybody is against being *more* "inclusive", I think they are against the push of being "inclusive" ("welcoming") at the expense of quality.

Comment: @Script47 You are really baffled? White male and SO are common terms by themselves and combining both should mean something like an SO where users are predominantly white male. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Trilarion but... what has that got to do with ***anything***? That's why I'm baffled, I don't see how the "white-male SO" is such a problem. If I get my answer from a white person or a black person or a pink person, why should that matter? That same question, can be posed for questions too, who cares who's asking? What is wrong with having a predominantly white site? Are we here to play identity politics or curate high quality Q&As through which ***all*** can benefit from, freely? The content is the important part, not who's contributing.

Comment: @Script47 I guess I understand you now. You probably disagree with this answer then. I started from "..What the concept of quality entails for me, one of the majority, might not be the same for anyone from a underrepresented group..", which would mean that the representation of the content matters too. In the end, it may be somewhat subjective what high quality Q&A actually is and how to best contribute to it.

Comment: Like it or not, *male privilege* and *majority privilege* are real things. Survey says: Native-English-speaking men are the majority on SO. That makes it easy for us to assume our outlook goes beyond normal to normative. That is, we fall into the trap of measuring other peoples' attitudes about quality as if ours are  correct, and theirs aren't.   You mentioned that there's more to a community than the quality of posts. You're right!

Comment: @O.Jones well, it's a english speaking site. If you go to es.SO or to pt.SO, or to jp.SO, I am willing to bet that demographics may be different.

Comment: "...(straight) white males [1], the majority of the SO users..." Is that known? Is that part of the developer survey (never taken it myself)?

Comment: @ouflak both ethnicity and gender are selectable, yes.

Comment: @Script47 I was just as baffled by the comment from Trilarion. I think he has his analysis sound, however his solution is way off, into being racist/sexist. To go further into the concept of quality. Its not about the content of the message (the code, the solution) but the way it is presented. Some people value the bits some of "us" call noize, and seeing those getting edited out hurts them, and might make them feel unwelcome. So as of today I decided to stop removing salutations from posts, period.

Comment: @O.Jones : regarding "ours [attitudes about quality] are correct, and theirs aren't" - let's make it a bit more practical. how do men and women differ in their attitudes towards quality? do you have an example of a question that is good from a male point of view but bad from a female point of view? Or vice versa? To be honest: I'd be very surprised if anyone can come up with a decent, practical example. And if you cannot provide an example, the whole point becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score -6):

I think almost everything that could have been said here has been said. But still I want to make a suggestion on how SO can support women in the industry. It's just a small thing but I think a **women coders chatroom** could be a nice thing.

I am aware, that this to some extent enforces a certain level of exclusion, however that's not nessecarily a problem. I absolutly agree that the discussion needs to be an open one and male developers need to be involved. However it is a simple fact, that women are a minority in the coding industry and it will take a long time for this to change. Meanwhile you can make the best out of it.

Let me outline the advantages I see for such a group:

- Beeing in a minority can be challenging if you are feeling alone. So while this might be the case at the workplace it doesnt need to be the case on SO. While here are relativly few women, in absolut number there are many. So utilise this and exchange yourself about challenges and solutions regarding how to address the problems implied by beeing a minority. This ultimatly makes the group stronger and can positivly impact our environment for both women and men.
- A smaller group can help you to be more open minded, talk more to people from different backgrounds, both personanlly and professionally. This can make you a better person and a better coder.
- and finally it can be fun.

Summarising: While the discussion needs to be open and men not only need to get used to women as team members but also value, women in the team, an internal perspective can contribute to this change. And I belive that SO is a platform that can supply an environment to help women become stronger and ultimatly overcome the differences. After all, its sad but true, that in cases of suppression/discrimination/etc. mostly the suppressed group needs to work harder on a change than the surpressing group

Comment: IMHO, I'm not sure giving minorities exclusivity will make us more inclusive, rather, it might divide us further. If the goal is to make people color blind / gender blind then I don't think this exclusivity will help.

Comment: Well ultimatly, this might be true, but this is a long long way to go (and I am not sure if this is desirable to 100% but anyways). Menawhile, any supprt can help. ANd also i want to point out that the exclusive part is not a substitute for an open discussion/ a process for finding a solution that involves everyone.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, that being said, '*any support can help*' can also lead to detriments in the future. All I'm saying is that we shouldn't rush into something to try and solve a problem and as a result, create more problems.

Comment: Anyone (with a certain amount of rep?) can create a chat room I believe.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, they can, but Im neiter a woman nor have I the required rep, after all it was just a suggestion :)

Answer (score -9):

I mostly ask questions, I don't use Meta (which appears to have a life of its own).

I don't particularly care about the age, gender, sex, skin color, religious creed, political bias, __________, or whatever characteristic of the person who answers. Most of the time I don't even read the names. I still think that *on the Internet no one knows you're a dog*.

All I care is that I get a polite (and this is subjective, as someone pointed out we don't all speak the same language even though we all use English); informative, clear, well-documented, technical, competent, informed answer.

Most of the times I do get such answers and this is why I like Stack Overflow; sometimes my questions go unanswered -I don't feel left out, it's life in the Internet- sometimes I can even contribute, which is great.

It seems as though all this fuss could easily be generated replacing "women" with whichever is the trendy "minority" these days. This is a technology-oriented site, the social aspect should be irrelevant (I'm sure there are other Stack Exchange sites for that).

Why Stack Overflow decided to discriminate in this year's poll is beyond be - again, I don't frequent Meta, I'm just an average user. It does seem like an exaggerated signal-to-noise ratio on something that on this site should be a non-issue.

Comment: I liked your first three paragraphs, then you drifted off. Sad :|

Comment: I don't see discrimination in polls tbh. Polls about specific demographic groups are done all the time, and there's no obligation to investigate all categories evenly or even at all. The whole point of this exercise is to find interesting and valueable data for SO to interpret, it makes sense they'd focus on underrepresented group.

Comment: I started reading this thinking "ah, an echo of my thoughts", but then it went a bit sideways. I really don't see the need to ask about sexuality or race in a poll for a Q&A developer site (I'm on the fence about gender). It's very politically correct, sure, and it's certainly big issues in the world. But on here, on SO, we're perceived through our avatar, nickname and score. I don't see myself as belonging to any specific group. If anyone feels unwelcome, or treated badly, this should be dealt with of course. Do we need to categorize it?

Comment: Probably worth noting that we've caught flak for *years* over the representation of women in the survey - specifically that *because a higher proportion of males respond to the survey* than would be indicated by the general population of working programmers, any conclusions drawn from the results are suspect. It's a valid criticism (though hardly the *only* source of skew, it's a big and obvious one), and feedback that we've taken extra care to try to listen to this year; we're not doing it to be trendy or hip, we're just trying to do right by the folks who take the time to participate.

Comment: @Mackan sums up what i said it less characters.

Comment: @Shog9 the "trendy" bit comes from the fact that there's been a lot of attention on women lately in the news, starting with #metoo, but i see your point, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @vesperto the #metoo movement and recent surge in efforts to achieve a more equal place in the world for women is not a "trend" anymore than the civil rights movement was a trend, or the women's suffrage movement, or the abolition of slavery, etc. (of course these are all US-centric events whereas #metoo itself is worldwide). These things may be trends in that lots of activity starts happening in that direction, but they are not "trendy" as in "a passing fad".

Comment: @TylerH those were/are all important milestones in society and, to an extent, they're ongoing processes. By trendy i mean that most of #metoo is not actual serious content but just noise. Yes these issues exist and should be tackled, most of what i see though is just attention-craving. And now i see that if "anything" can even remotely be framed as women vs men then it's immediately blown out of proportion 'cos #metoo. That's noise and it won't help. Maybe i didn't convey my thoughts well but, meh, English is not m native language.