# Question put at hold as too broad and I have no code but added more details

Tags: discussion, specific-question, needs-more-focus

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to program my computer to open a file with a certain application and change the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591853/how-to-program-my-computer-to-open-a-file-with-a-certain-application-and-change)

Could someone help me understand why my question was put on hold as too broad? I got a reply saying my description was vague, so I added more details, but if it seems broad/vague that's only because it's a question regarding how to start a program, not regarding a fix or bug. I can't include any code because I haven't written any. I was just looking for ideas on how to approach the problem.

Let me know what information the question leaves you wondering/how I can fix it.

EDIT: I feel like people might be assuming there is more to this task than there is. Here is every single step I have to complete for each file:

1. Drag the file from Finder into a QT4Image window to open it with QT4Image. The default exposure and gamma on QT4Image are appropriate, so no changes need to be made there. It requires no visual confirmation, it just needs to be opened on QT4Image.
2. Click File -> Save As.
3. Copy and paste the file name, and add ".png" to the end of it. The file name is the exact same as it was, except now ends in .png instead of .exr Ex. file32.exr would become file32.png
4. Put it in the right folder (all the .png files are going in the same folder).

After my clarifying comment, all this information was present in my question. However, people still asked for more context. There is no more context.

The only reason I tagged it as Python was because Stack Overflow required me to tag a language and I know Python -- I guess I should have also specified that the language did not matter to me.

Also, I wasn't asking for anyone to write the code for me. I was asking for ideas regarding how to go about this problem, which could be in the form of a place to start, or links to resources, etc. Is that sort of thing not welcome on here? Please let me know.

Comment: The information you presented in your comment (the name of the application you need to do the saving/renaming with) is rather important to answering your question i'd assume. If that action can't be done programatically using the application... that makes this a whole nother kind of question.

Comment: I can understand the downvotes on the original question but not on this question on meta. A user comes here and asks in a clear way how to improve. What better can happen? Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: @gnat I think that would be related, but not a great duplicate... This is a special case.

Comment: This can't be a duplicate of asking about too broad if the specific question referenced is not an example of a too broad question (let alone this is about a specific-question and answers have nuance to this particular question).

Comment: Regarding your latest edit, evil_scientist; it makes answering significantly more complicated when you add automating a particular interactive program vs asking for the task to be done (without introducing the hoop of trying to automate an interactive program).  As I indicate in my answer, your best bet is to edit your question and leave all that out; as unless I miss my guess, you can achieve the same result without even using that particular program. (a question being complicated to answer is not on the OP; since they can't know how complex something is; though it'd be nice).

Comment: Stack Overflow does have a tag called [tag:language-agnostic] if the language doesn't matter to you. However, with that being said, I'm not sure how wise it is to ask for someone to give suggestions using a language you *don't* know.

Answer (score 25):

This is the crux of your question:

> It's a trivial task but very time consuming, and I am wondering if people have any advice how I would go about coding this instead of doing it manually?

The components of your question are:

> I have hundreds of .exr files that I need to convert to .png -- however, each file has to be opened with an application to ensure it has the proper exposure, etc. (which are conveniently the default settings on the app), then saved to a folder.

The basic pieces of automation are there; a large amount of work needs to be accomplished, and the way to approach is clearly defined.

***However***, that alone doesn't narrow the actual crux of your question.  You're asking us how we would go about automating this workflow.

What we *don't* know is:

- If we can pass files in to the second application on the command line, or if they have to be somewhere else
- If the second application requires visual confirmation or if you can rely on passing flags and an exit code
- **What attempts you've made at solving the problem**

Stack Overflow works best for questions like this if you come to the table with a clear direction and some portion of it that you're stuck at.  Right now, you're at the desk with a blank piece of paper, and so are we; we're not going to be of much value to you if we're guessing *too*.

Comment: Questions should not be closed because the user hasn’t attempted anything. That’s a reason to downvote, not close.

Comment: The lack of an attempt isn't the issue. It's lack of direction. An attempt would provide direction, but it isn't the only way to provide direction.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker:  It's one of three components I list.  It's definitely not one that can be overlooked, but I would also imagine the actual part where someone wants to integrate with an application to provide validation would need to be checked to be sure that this kind of automation is even possible to begin with.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I know I've posted this comment before previously, but I believe it holds here: With all due respect I disagree, I don't necessarily want a code attempt, but I want OP to have put some thought into how they'd solve the problem: "I know that some may disagree here but [*"gimme teh codez" is not the best way to introduce yourself to a community. A demonstration of effort proves that they're willing to take the time to help themselves first." "*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179035/how-does-proof-of-effort-make-a-question-better/179038#179038)

Comment: @NickA feel free to downvote. There’s nothing new here; if you close a question due to lack of effort, expect a moderator (if they see it) to reopen it.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253096/16587

Comment: @GeorgeStocker *"[Has the asker put enough thought into the problem to formulate a clear, specific question? - We have multiple close reasons for #2: Unclear, Too Broad and a grab-bag of more specific reasons under Off Topic.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/3270037)"* (Note I'm not necessarily saying that it should be closed as Too Broad, but it *should* be closed)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker:  You're *painfully* overlooking the "validation" part.  And that's the part that I have a hang-up on.  How do we know if the application can actually do the validation in an automated way?  **That's the context *I'm* missing as a Python expert** to even bother *attempting* a solution!  (Just for the reference - I mention it ***twice*** in my bullet points above.)

Comment: @makoto then give an answer without it; or give an answer that launches the file after the exposure is done. Neither of those make the question too broad, at best they make the answerer say “I can’t give you interactive validation, but I can save it without overwriting the original or show you how to programmatically launch it so you can check.

Comment: Sounds like you've got it right where you want it then @GeorgeStocker; in that case, since you truly believe that it isn't too broad and you also hold the power to do so, feel *encouraged* to answer it.  I've stated my position on this question, and you've demonstrated yours.

Comment: On second thought, I think the question *is* borderline answerable, though only with broad strokes, and using AHK rather than Python. (1) Get a list of file paths to be converted (2) Loop: (a) Open file with `Run`, wait for QT4Image to finish opening it with `WinWait` (b) Send keystrokes to the program to save the file with the right name, in the right place

Comment: @CertainPerformance:  If [this is the application being used](https://www.iboostup.com/app/edu.cornell.graphics.qt4image) (oh look, another missed detail about the problem domain!), then AutoHotKey [would be out of play](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153930/autohotkey-equivalent-for-os-x).

Comment: @Makoto answer added: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388757/16587

Comment: @GeorgeStocker maybe not, but most of these questions [usually fall under the TB close reason](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), not because of a lack of research, but because "if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format". Judging by [the file format](https://www.openexr.com/about.html), correctly adjusting the exposure (as asked in the question) is extremely broad. What's "proper exposure"? How on earth do you calculate that? Is it universal?

Comment: @Zoe I address that in my answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker no, you don't. You're also forgetting the conversion part. Loading and parsing a .exr is a book of its own, and converting it to PNG as well requires a parser that manages to convert the formats. There's libraries for that (and probably several, meaning it has "too many valid answers"), automatically calculating the correct exposure (unless it's a static value - also not mentioned in the question) takes a few years and a team of ML experts to identify what exposure is correct. And, agian, what is correct? That means there's no way to determine which answers are correct.

Comment: It's also unlikely to be useful to anyone else depending on the definition of what exposure is correct. Converting the image itself is one thing, but modifying it requires a whole different approach. You need to know what data to modify, find a way to validate it, then find the right way to identify the correct exposure, followed by converting that to a .png format. Distinct? Sure! So is "how do I code an app that does <something>", but it doesn't mean it's easily answerable.

Comment: @Zoe if we disallowed all questions that needed libraries for their answers we'd never have any answers.  APIs are all around us.  We disallow questions that ask which library to use for a given task; we don't disallow questions that require usage of a library to answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker You're missing my point. I'm not saying the use of libraries is the problem, but when it requires thousands of lines of code and thousands of images to train on, that isn't easily answerable. OP refers to it as a "trivial task", but that's because it's powered by a brain. Answering the question, unless the exposure has a static value (which, again, isn't mentioned in the question), **requires a replacement for a brain** to find the right exposure. There's years and years of research poured into ML, but not a single way to compress the answer into a format that doesn't take

Comment: a team of ML researchers and a pool of data the size of Google to write up.

Comment: No, but we ask questions to be reasonably scoped. That's part of the _"with enough detail to identify an adequate answer"_. That question wasn't, and considering the question asker comments in their latest edit, wasn't going to be.

Comment: @Zoe I'm referencing this line in your comment: "There's libraries for that (and probably several, meaning it has "too many valid answers"), .  Did you not mean for that to come across as having lots of libraries to solve a problem means its too broad?

Comment: Very funny, @GeorgeStocker.  I believed that the context of me asking you to answer the question was referring to [the OP's question on the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591853/how-to-program-my-computer-to-open-a-file-with-a-certain-application-and-change).  Since you still believe it to not be too broad, are you gonna try and tackle that now?  *Especially* in light of what context the OP has added to *this* question?

Comment: @Makoto [Already did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388757/16587); you can say it's unsatisfying, or you can downvote it, but it doesn't change my view on it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker No. Take C++: many questions ask about problems that can be solved with Boost. Off the top of my head, "How do I load a file?". I guarantee there's a Boost header that handles it. If the answer says something like "Alternatively, you can use Boost: <code>", that's wildly different from "Use this library for parsing, then combine this code written with this library for detecting exposure, then you can use this library to change the law byte data produced by the first one...". This isn't a library question, this specific question asks for an entire tech stack.

Comment: But I doubt you see the problem. But try to imagine the components required to answer the question: you need to load  the file, parse the file, be able to modify it, find how to modify it (this alone is extremely broad if we're not talking static values. Optimizing a ML model can be done in many ways), actually modify it, convert it to the .png format, and save it. What you're forgetting to ask is "how does one calculate what to modify"? If it's a dynamic model and requires a brain, ML is the only way to go. Improving image quality alone is a massive subject, and that's usually with scaling.

Comment: @zoe we have different perspectives on the question; my answer goes into my perspective and what would make it a better question. At a certain point, programming becomes the art of doing the possible. We don’t take what beginners think they want  at face value because they’re unlikely to know what they really need. Instead we use our experience and judgement to give them answers that achieve their goals without taking into account how they perceive it should be done. As my answer details, i’d Edit out figuring out the “right” exposure and saving that for a separate question.

Comment: I don’t think it’s purposeful but one critical part of being  able to help people is to not hang them with their own rope, but cut the rope when you see it might be too long.

Answer (score -28):

> Could someone help me understand why my question was put on hold as too broad? I got a reply saying my description was vague, so I added more details, but if it seems broad/vague that's only because it's a question regarding how to start a program, not regarding a fix or bug.

[It wasn't too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323713/16587).   A majority of the three close voters picked 'too broad', and with the three vote experiment, that's all it took.

If we look at the close reason text for 'too broad':

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple ***distinct*** questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. (emphasis added)

Are there multiple distinct questions being asked?  That is; could you do the middle part of what you want to do programmatically without having to do step 1 (opening the file) or step 3 (changing its extension)?

*Possibly* #3, but not #1. Opening and closing the file is part and parcel to changing any attributes of that file. In fact, if a person chopped up their questions like that, they're just as likely to annoy others as they are to make others happy.

So did you edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail?

**Yes**

This also exposes a problem in our close reason: if a question didn't have enough detail, that should make it 'unclear what you're asking', not too broad; but English is imperfect.

As written, If I squint and tilt my head in the right way I can see a little bit of vagueness, but I had no problems reading the question and understanding what you were asking for, and so that makes "unclear what you're asking" out for me as well.

If I had to boil down your question; you're asking:

> I have hundreds of files that I want to change their exposure and extension from .exr to .png.  How do I do this in python?

You actually make things worse for yourself the more you specify here.  There are hopefully good libraries that do this in python; and you're looking to get it done.  You shouldn't care how it's done, just that it's done.  If you start to specify a program, you fall into two traps:

1. The specialization trap.  If I ask a programmer to build a website; I don't care what framework they use.  If I ask a PHP developer to build a website in .NET Core, all of a sudden they're going to hem and haw and wonder if it can even be done.
2. The utility trap. Unless that program is used by lots of people who frequent Stack Overflow and consider it a programmer's tool, it's easier to peg the problem as "not related to programming" and ask you to take your problem elsewhere; in the same way that yes, Zoho lets you write scripts, but they have this weird esoteric homegrown language that still gives me nightmares.

In your case; keeping it light on *how* you want it done helps you get an answer more easily and it helps others to not get caught up in either of those two traps. So unless you're going to get struck by lightning if you don't use a particular program to solve your problem, leave out that detail.

Here's how your question looks now:

> I have hundreds of .exr files that I need to convert to .png -- however, each file has to be opened with an application to ensure it has the proper exposure, etc. (which are conveniently the default settings on the app), then saved to a folder. It's a trivial task but very time consuming, and I am wondering if people have any advice how I would go about coding this instead of doing it manually?
>
> The particular application is QT4Image, and each .exr file needs to be opened with that so it has the right exposure, and then saved as "[same file name].png". Instead of opening each individual .exr file with QT4Image, and then clicking "Save As" and pasting the file name.png, I'd like to code this. Any thoughts?

And here's how I'd edit it:

> I have hundreds of files that I want to change their exposure and extension from `.exr` to `.png`.   I'll ask how to programmatically determine the correct exposure in a separate question; for our purposes assume it's an input to the script.
>
> How do I do this in python?

Comment: I think your edit made it *worse*.  Now we lose context into what program is being used, which would've motivated command-line solutions for those who are well-versed in it, and we are still faced with an overly broad "how do I do X in Y"-style question.    I get that you might want to save this question, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

Comment: @Makoto so ask that question instead of attacking?

Comment: If you feel me to be attacking you, we can take this to chat later.  I'm definitely not attacking you; I'm explaining to you why the OP's original question on the main site was too broad, and why your edit made that worse than what you had intended.

Comment: I'm having trouble even seeing how this is a programming problem to begin with; all we have is, "I have this task that needs to be automated", while assuming the solution has to involve code.  I don't think adding, "with code" to a problem automatically means it's a programming problem.

Comment: @fbueckert I address that here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388734/question-put-at-hold-as-too-broad-and-i-have-no-code-but-added-more-details/388757?noredirect=1#comment723490_388736

Comment: So...because the asker doesn't know any better, we have to help them?  I'm going to strongly disagree that a lack of knowledge automatically entitles assistance from our end.  That flies in the face of why we close questions in the first place.

Comment: @fbueckert we got rid of the 'minimal understanding' close reason for precisely this reason.

Comment: You're arguing a strawman, @George.  I don't care if they don't understand; I care about it *actually being a programming problem*.  Asking it here doesn't make it one.

Comment: @fbueckert what is programming if not automation of otherwise manual tasks?  Did you know that there are large swaths of organizations that still, to this day, refer to their programming departments as "automation"?

Comment: Ah, I see where the disconnect is.  You see it as de facto code required; I see it as an XY problem, where the assumed solution requires code.  Yes, it takes expertise to recognize that it doesn't, but not having that knowledge doesn't make it a problem within a programming scope.

Comment: @fbueckert I don't see it as 'code required'; I see that the OP asked it on this site, asking if there was a way in python to do what they want to do.  I'm not sure how much more programming you get. "We only allow programming questions by people who know how to program" is a bit gate-keeperish.

Comment: See, that's where we disagree.  I'm pointing out that asking about a task, and appending, "in code" to the problem makes it a programming problem.  That's why I think it's an XY problem.  Is it gatekeeping to require askers to present a problem that meets our scope?  I disagree with that statement.

Comment: And there *is* a barrier to entry; [you need a modicum of knowledge in the problem space to participate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378753/spooked-by-robotic-repetitive-questions-in-the-first-post-review/378769#comment661548_378769).  Is that really gatekeeping?