# Why does the direct link to the Ask a Question Wizard lead to a 404 for users who aren't in the test group?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, 404-not-found, ask-question-wizard-2018

I was trying to access the Ask A Question wizard, for the purposes of answering a question over on Meta Stack Exchange. The link to the wizard is supposedly at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard. For some users, it [shows an actual wizard](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7521229#7521229). But when I try to click on it, I get a 404 error.

[The Ask Question Wizard Is Now In Testing!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing) explains that the wizard is only shown to users who are a member of a test group. Evidently, I'm not a member of it. But I would have expected that the way the test group would work would be by redirecting users who are members to the wizard, and that the direct link to it would work for everyone.

Why was the decision made to block non-members of the test group from being able to use the wizard entirely?

Comment: See [The Ask Question Wizard Is Now In Testing!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057)

Comment: *For most people reading this, probably nothing. If you arrive to the site incognito and create a new account, you have approximately a 50/50 shot of seeing the new interface as you ask your first couple of questions*

Comment: So this is only avaliable for new accounts, in an A/B testing setup.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That explains why the link to /ask may redirect to the wizard view, but doesn't explain why the direct link to the wizard isn't available for others.

Comment: Why should it be available to others if they are not part of the test group?

Comment: @MartijnPieters If they really want to use or try out the wizard, or in this case, if they want to help figure out why the wizard led to a user asking a blatantly off-topic question on MSE.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Since edited; not a duplicate now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to recall that this *still* is a test. We gave test users an opportunity to take a survey telling us about their experience with the wizard. As people ask questions, we can see [how the community responds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests) to these questions. We're going to use this data to evaluate the experimental feature and plan (potentially significant) changes to test next.

The main reason to block the control group is that it messes with the data we are trying to collect. My guess is that people who go out of their way to try out the new feature will ask better questions on average than those who arrive organically. Now we do some sanity checks in our analysis:

```
  AND NOT ( -- Remove edge cases
            (ask_a_question_template__grp = 1 AND CreatedWithWizard = 1)
             OR (ask_a_question_template__grp = 2 AND CreatedWithWizard = 0)
  )
```

But as a general rule, it's best to avoid letting the control group use an experimental feature. [Ideally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinded_experiment), we wouldn't even let the control group know about the test while the test is running.

We're currently compiling results and feedback (including meta feedback). When this test is finalized, we'll share our finding here.

(Fun fact: I can't see the wizard either.)

Comment: Why not show a nice error message (or at least a 403) to users not in the group (e.g. "you aren't a member of the test group. nothing to see here, move along") instead of a confusing 404 error?

Comment: I wasn't directly involved in that decision, but I think the reason is to avoid over-complicating it. When we have a gated feature (normally gated by [privilege level](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)), we just use a 404 for people who don't have access.

Comment: Not always, though; trying to access `/tools` on my <10k account gives me a nice error message "this page requires more privileges" and a link to the relevant privilege.

Comment: "The main reason to block the control group is that it messes with the data we are trying to collect" If that's  your goal, then this has the opposite of the intended effect.  Now you're forcing anyone who wants to test this to create new accounts until they get into the test, a mild annoyance for them, but *they are now impacting test data*.  If you provide a way for anyone to see the wizard *you have the ability to exclude anyone using that method from being included in stats* (or tracking stats of it separately, to see how those users fair vs. normal users).

Comment: @Servy: One of the reasons we announce this sort of test on meta is that we trust our users not to mess with the results. But we can't say the same thing if the feature became noticed by a bunch of Hacker News/reddit/Twitter/etc. users. I understand the frustration of being locked out, but that's just how A/B tests are supposed to work. Hopefully people seeking a workaround will refrain from actually posting their questions via the wizard.