# Why was my meta question about the Ask a Question Wizard not reopened?

Tags: discussion, meta, reopen-closed

A while ago, I asked a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379560/why-does-the-direct-link-to-the-ask-a-question-wizard-lead-to-a-404-for-users-wh) about why the direct link to the Ask a Question Wizard leads to a 404 error for some users including me, but links to an actual page for some other users. It was instantly closed as a duplicate by a moderator of the original announcement, which mentions that the wizard is only being shown to users who are part of a test group.

I later edited my question, to make it instead ask why the SE team decided to make the link 404 for users who are not in the test group (i.e. block users who aren't in the group from being able to use the wizard entirely), rather than leaving the direct link open for everyone and simply redirecting test group members from the normal question asking form to the wizard view. That question is *not* answered in the duplicate target. Despite that, it was [reviewed "Leave Closed"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/22408) in the reopen queue.

I checked and re-checked the duplicate target, and it doesn't even mention anything regarding 404 errors or blocking users who aren't part of the test group from accessing the wizard. The ending question in my post is, "Why was the decision made to block non-members of the test group from being able to use the wizard entirely?", and I don't see where that's answered.

Can I please get clarification as to why it's still a duplicate, preferably from one of the users who reviewed it as "Leave Closed"? If not, can it please be reopened?

Comment: Because the answer is “SE only wants to make the AAQW to a select group of users”, which is stated in the original announcement.

Comment: @DanBron I'm sorry, but I did not see that in the original announcement. Where is it?

Answer (score 6):

In the announcement your question was marked a duplicate to, Tim says:

> I can pretty confidently say that if you have enough rep to not see ads, you'll be extremely unlikely to see the wizard while it's in testing

For me, it clearly follows that you either can see the wizard while in testing, or you can't. Since you are in the group that can't see the wizard, the direct link doesn't work for you.

If an Stack Overflow employee (the only kind of user who can give you additional details about testing methodologies being used) want and can answer your original question, they'll be able to re-open it single-handedly. (Although it would probably better to keep your question closed and add the details in the announcement, if we were going that route).

For any other user, the question is appropriately closed, IMO.

Comment: "see" could mean "see it in the wild, when clicking the Ask Question button". That's not a reason for not being able to access it via the direct link. It does not address my question.

Comment: @gparyani When you're doing AB testing, you kinda don't want to mess up your stats. You prevent people from accessing it intentionally. I'm not certain this is the reasoning in this case but it's 100% understandable that someone testing a feature would intentionally limit who has access to it.

Comment: @gparyani Could mean something else. Since you can't access it with the directl link, I think it does answer your question conclusively.

Comment: @Catija When you're analyzing the data, isn't it easy to simply ignore questions that are posted through the wizard for users who aren't in the beta?

Comment: Also, if you really insist on users not in the group not having access to the wizard, can't you show them a nice error page, e.g. "you don't have access to the wizard", rather than just a plain 404?

Comment: @yivi The ending question in my previous closed-as-duplicate post is, "Why was the decision made to block non-members of the test group from being able to use the wizard entirely?". That's not answered in the dupe target.

Comment: @Catija It's pretty trivial to keep stats on users *you show* a feature via AB testing, and not include the stats from users that manually activated the feature (or even better, just track the stats separately, in case there's any interesting insight there).

Comment: @gparyani so you really disagree with "duplicate" reason and want to get it closed as "opinion based" or "too broad"? As yivi said no one but actual SO employees (who have powers roughly equal to diamond mods) can answer your question (we can express random opinions or chit-chat which is not what good answer should be). Since we don't usually re-close questions with different reason your post so far stays closed as duplicate (even if it may not be *the best* closing reason for that particular post - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262211/).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov SE employees check this site too. It's perfectly reasonable to ask a question that can only be answered by SE employees; I've done so several times on MSE. It's not opinion-based or too broad; it has a definite answer.

Comment: Also, the flowchart you linked goes directly to "vote to reopen" if the question is closed as a duplicate, but isn't.

Comment: @gparyani I totally support your idea that people should always think the same way you think... Unfortunately there way too many people having they own opinions (like they may even think that your edit was not convincing enough and duplicate indeed answers your question).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Which is why I asked in the question, why did others vote to leave it closed? Why did they think it was answered? Clearly I may have been missing something.

Comment: Either they reviewed it that way because they had a reason to, or because they were reviewing on a whim. I generally trust people to not act on whims, so I'd like to know what the reason is.

Comment: I'd personally vote as "keep closed" too - question linked as duplicate calls the behavior expected and "why you @#$# implemented corner case X that way when I'd do *that feature* differently" is rarely productive as in most cases no one actually *implements* such behavior by leaving whatever default one as long as it satisfies requirements. Making people to spend time to figure out why exactly it happens is not very useful from my point of view.

Comment: @gparyani there is no way to know why people voted one way or another - @-ask them directly and invite to this post (I think you'd have to do it on some random post of theirs as I'm not sure if re-open voters can be addressed that way on original post)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Meh, it doesn't matter now. An SE employee reopened it and answered it.