# Identify duplicates in "Ask a question" wizard

Tags: discussion, ask-question-wizard-2018

On a daily basis I encounter lots of duplicates and badly (or just not) researched questions. It is endurable, but annoying.

I think that SO should recognize duplicate questions more easily.
This could be implemented with the new "Ask a question"-wizard, which is currenly in a [public testing phase](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing), as a next step.

In the current "default" question editor there is a list with similar posts which may have an answer. An example from my question:

[image: A list of question-links that may already have an answer]

In my opinion this list should be more prominent, and the asker should be **forced** to read through it.

If the listed similar questions don't answer the question, the asker should be able to explain and clarify in detail, maybe with a minimum of characters, why these other questions don't answer theirs. This could then be displayed at the top of the question.

Maybe something like this:

> The question [some other question] doesn't answer mine, because [detailed description]

Though this could still be abused, as an asker just could write some gibberish like this, which is no great explanation:

> [some other question] doesn't work for me

All in all this is not a feature-request (yet?) but I would like to hear what you think about this, and if it would help to eliminate exact duplicate questions.

Comment: As soon as you use the word forced, bold or not, you've already lost. No, no forced anything. Encouragement is the best that can be done and should be done. Having a short but highly relevant list of duplicates to me is the only thing that would need improving. The six items that your screenshot shows is already TL;DR. Improving the duplicate match/search I believe is already on the roadmap, but I can't find a meta post that proves this just yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In our research, we've discovered that duplicate questions are a common frustration for active answerers *and* askers. We've long known that dealing with questions that have been asked and answered on the site is a burden to our curators. Meanwhile, askers generally would like to find a duplicate question to avoid needing to ask their own. (Little known fact: many users are *anxious about participating on Stack Overflow*.) We sometimes assume the reason a person would ask a duplicate is because they are too lazy to search. But when we talk to people who have tried to use the site, we find that's not actually true.

Instead, people are unable to identify a duplicate question. The reasons might include:

1. **The asker doesn't understand the technology well enough to identify a duplicate.** For instance, one of the [most linked-to questions about bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash?sort=MostLinked&uqlId=20) is [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) Yet when you look at [the questions tagged as duplicate of that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/10067266), you'll see that many of them have titles that are completely unrelated to quoting shell variables. To those of us who have been bit by filenames with whitespace (to name a [handy example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22091309)) the connection is clear. But there's really no way a developer who hasn't had that experience would ever spot the duplicate.
2. **The target question title is unclear.** To take another bash FAQ: [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within) (I apparently upvoted this question before [someone changed the title](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59895/revisions).) This is *so close* to being a good title, but it really needs to have "the script itself" added to the end of the title. (I already edited it.) Good titles help since they summarize the core of the question. A bad title risks steering askers away from the solution they are looking for.
3. **The target question isn't tagged with the technology the asker is using.** Bash questions are often identical to ksh and other Bourne shell derivatives. So if the asker is using ksh and the answer they are looking for is tagged [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), that hampers the various mechanisms we have for surfacing duplicates. (This also intersects with #1 since not everyone can name the ways Korn differs from Bourne.)
4. **Information overload.** There are *a lot* of things to think about when asking a question. If you are focused on avoiding appearing as if you are asking for a library recommendation, you might miss the prompts to look for duplicate questions. We add so much guidance, it's difficult to focus on any one bit of advice. (This is a place the wizard has a chance to shine.)
5. **Sometimes the answers on the target question, um, don't really help.** This is so irritating to see, but I see people arguing over whether a question is really a duplicate and often the answers to the target question fail to answer the ostensible duplicate. Sometimes this is a subset of #1, but other times the people voting to close don't really understand the new question.
6. **People use different words to ask their question.** [Some duplicate questions are helpful](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

In any case, the current implementation of the wizard has a step between entering the title and writing the question body that shows a list of duplicate questions:

[image: How do I untar multiple files?]

Obviously we don't *force* users to read through those questions (even assuming that were possible), but this page eliminates many of the distractions present in the "classic" ask page. It also creates an incentive to consider the titles by the label of the button to move forward asserting that none of those questions helped.

One of our active projects (in the initial discovery phase) is to improve the algorithm for detecting and the UX for presenting potential duplicates. This has potential to help curate new questions *and* avoid unpleasant experiences for new users.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your time writing this answer. I have to agree with all points you've mentioned, explained and shown. As a registered user I of course can't get direct access to the new help wizard (and I usually don't ask questions) so I've not seen this section about the duplicates. But this answers my question and I am glad to hear that the SO-Team is really working on improving this crucial part when asking a question. Again thank you very much! This answers my question thoroughly

Comment: "Meanwhile, askers generally would like to find a duplicate question to avoid needing to ask their own. (Little known fact: many users are anxious about participating on Stack Overflow.)" And yet, it seems like Meta constantly has people complaining about their question being wrongly dupe-closed, almost always because of some irrelevant pedantic detail....