# A user decided he did not want his data on the web, so he removed it from my answer

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I posted an answer around 3 months ago in response to a question that initially had an input data set as a test case. Around 2 days ago I got a notification showing that my answer had been edited and something like 500 characters were removed from the body. Following that my (rather long) answer was changed to display a message which said:

> deleted some data that should not be posted on public discussion forum.

For the sake of honesty, I got a little bit salty and edited his question to say:

> this question initially referred to data that should not have been shared on a public forum.

I have since rolled both edits back because I recognized what I did was wrong and was remorseful (his edit on my question, and my edit on his question).

Perhaps he doesn't want to delete the question for some reason, but I feel like that would've been a better solution than editing out my answer. How should I handle this in the future (obviously my initial solution to retaliate was not "best practices").

Comment: Kind of funny that when people handle their mistakes like that it generally ends up producing a response that draws even more attention to their "private" data.

Comment: SNL Institution is murky, banking people get their underwear in a bundle in a hurry.  Just obfuscate the data, Acme as the company name, explosives as their product.  We usually try to point out that the original was copied by a hundred vampire web sites, but that's pretty optional from your end.

Comment: @Don'tPanic [The Streisand Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect) is the name you're looking for.

Comment: @Luc apparently so! I didn't realize it had a name. Makes sense it would happen pretty much the same way everywhere, though.

Comment: Well... Some people still need to learn that the term "the Streisand effect" is a warning to be heeded...

Comment: I'm confused; did your answer use the same private data that was in the original question? Shouldn't it have been removed from *both*, or at least replaced with some dummy data that would have made both continue to make sense? (Along with a request to a mod to have the sensitive data expunged from the history.)

Comment: My answer used the data he provided initially, as I literally copy pasted his dataset into my script. It appears to be rolled back to the original post.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Deleting necessary portions of a post is considered *vandalism*, pretty much regardless of the motivation. So, deleting a large chunk of code that is necessary to understand the question and required to keep the answers coherent, well, that's vandalism.

Vandalism should either be reverted by rolling back the edit, or, when that fails, flagging the post for moderator attention.

An edit that *sanitized* the code, but otherwise kept its structure and meaning intact would be fine. But an edit *removing* the code altogether is not.

Deleting the question isn't really an acceptable solution, either, because it would have thrown away the work you put into composing your answer. It also misses an important mission of Stack Overflow, which is to build a library of high-quality answers to practical programming problems. In other words, we aren't just here to help the original asker. We're here to help an entire generation of programmers who have these questions and can find the answers through Google. Deleting questions, and taking good answers with them, tends to subvert that mission, rather than further it.

In terms of policy, we don't really have much sympathy for people who share code that "should not have been shared on a public forum". We don't police legal issues, and all submissions to this website are governed by a perpetual license for Stack Overflow to distribute the content, provided they adhere to the license's terms (namely, attribution). Moderators don't handle takedown notices at all. If we are asked, we direct the request to the Stack Overflow employees and/or legal department. I declined two flags today from a student asking to delete a question they had asked about their homework because—surprise surprise—it's against their school's policy to cheat on your homework.

Comment: In this case, I think the data that used to be in the question is pretty significant for the question. As it stands right now, after the edits, it is a question about transforming the data without example source data. Shouldn't that all be rolled back?

Comment: Uh yeah, @Cerbrus, that's basically the whole point of my answer.

Comment: Just summarizing / confirming I read the answer correctly :D

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree and have accordingly rolled back to the last version of the question that contained sample data.

Comment: *"Hey, that's vandalism."*

Comment: I feel like that's supposed to be a joke or a memetic reference, @commandertuna, but I'm embarrassed to say I don't know what it refers to.

Comment: @CodyGray The only thing it refers to is me when somebody touches my crap. You have nothing to be ashamed of xd

Comment: *I declined two flags today from a student asking to delete a question they had asked about their homework because—surprise surprise—it's against their school's policy to cheat on your homework.* It's also unfortunate that we're [not allowed to provide a reminder](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/334823/revisions) about such policies in the FAQ about homework questions.

Comment: @WBT That last revision makes no sense to me. I asked the person who deleted that bullet for their rationale, just in case I'm missing something. Our policy on homework questions is basically that we don't care. They should be treated identically to all other questions & answers from a moderation perspective. But that doesn't mean we can't provide advice to the students asking them. You might also be interested in the fact that [the team is building an Ask Question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057), where one of the options will be "homework" to make such guidance more visible.

Comment: Hopefully, that guidance is, they should not submit homework questions :-)

Answer (score 15):

If you want to take the time to, and it's easy enough to do without damaging the post, you could edit the answer such that it uses slightly different data, still equally effective for the purposes of the post, but not what this person apparently wants to keep private.   You don't *have* to, but if you want to be nice, this is always an option.

But you can always choose to rollback the edit vandalizing the post.  You don't *have* to do any more.  If they continue to remove the content, you can flag the post for moderator attention saying that they're vandalizing  your post.

If you want to, or they keep making a fuss and you don't want to escalate it to a moderator, you can inform the user that they can submit a DMCA takedown request if the original question's content was submitted without proper authorization from the owner of that content.  (If they're authorized to provide the data, but simply didn't want to, then they have no recourse at all.  It's a cat that can't get put back in the bag.  They licenced the content with a permissive license, and can't revoke it.)  That's what the moderator is going to tell them if you leave it up to the mods.  I suppose you could also ask them to do what I mentioned in my first paragraph, and edit the data to be data with the same relevant properties for the purposes of the question, but not the data they don't want to publicize.  Assuming they can come up with new data that doesn't change the meaning of the question, that's an acceptable edit.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that OP's retaliatory edit to the question was inappropriate, though it is good that OP recognized that and reverted it on their own.

Comment: @TylerH They admitted as much in the question, so I didn't see a need to comment further.

Comment: They admitted they reverted the action but did not offer any reason why (such as remorse). IMHO it's important to point out that it's not OK especially since OP didn't give a reason why; good actions can be commended but bad actions should still be identified.

Comment: Would you like me to add an edit that I rolled back the retaliation out of remorse? Obviously, I rolled it back because I realized it was wrong and decided not to behave like a child. I was remorseful, so I undid my wrong-doing.

Comment: @TylerH It's not like they edited in some personal insult.  The text was simply noise that had no business being in the answer, being meta commentary on revisions to the post.  And they removed it.  That's not something that requires a public apology or anything.

Comment: I have since added that I was remorseful to my post to make it more appeasing.

Comment: @Servy The op replaced the *entire* text of **the question** with "this question initially referred to data that should not have been shared on a public forum..." before rolling it back about 3 minutes before asking this Q here on Meta.

Comment: @d_kennetz That's good; thank you for expanding upon that.

Comment: @TylerH They didn't include a link, the meta question just says that they added that to the post, not that they removed the rest of the content to put it there.

Comment: @Servy the question says "I edited the question to say <...>" which, I admit, is ambiguous. I, however, went to the post itself to be sure of the context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863927/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-yaml-to-a-dataframe-or-somehow-flatten-or-normalize