# What is "Well i asked this question in hamework help section" about?

Tags: discussion, homework, ask-question-wizard-2018

I just saw this comment under a post currently being obliterated, as it is a homework dump (literally a copy-paste):

> Well i asked this question in hamework help section

This, exactly as written, was a response to a comment explaining the situation to OP.

Does anyone know where could this comment be coming from?

If this actually exists in a misleading form somewhere, there may need to be  some wording adjustment to this homework help section to better explain how to write a specific (homework) question, possibly with the link to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). With an emphasis on providing the start of a solution, and never just copy-paste the problem.

Comment: I'll add this would be mainly for the new asker's benefit (a-la welcome them), as these posts never last long anyway.

Comment: The dumps are alive and well in Bash, Sed, Awk and several other scripting tags. Those tags enjoy some of the lowest standards on Stack Overflow. OP should switch to scripting and folks will do his homework for them.

Comment: The misspell in the quote is part of the original. Please do not "fix" it as that would no longer be a proper quote.

Comment: Maybe at least make the title correct so it doesn't read like you're asking what "hamework" is ;) The exact quote is already in the body for reference, not that anyone is really helped by the misspelling being kept in-tact.

Comment: @Gimby I am a bit an hardliner with the use of quotes, and for me at least, seeing the title immediately makes it clear to me the author is not attributing said statement to themselves, and properly understands the error. On the other hand, I do not mind using the cheap, SO version of click-bait to get attention to this issue :)

Comment: I may be taking too much credit, but the answer on Yivi's link received 100 votes in a couple of days, moving it to second place.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I imagine it's a misinterpretation of this part of the "ask a question" wizard:

> [image: ask a question wizard step 1]

The following step includes this tip, but it might not be descriptive enough for many users:

> [image: ask a question wizard step 2]

If you feel this needs addressing you can upvote [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381732/6881240) under [The Ask Question Wizard is Live!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live), which deals with exactly this issue.

Comment: Good catch. I have to leave my PC now, but I will later try to modify the post to a feature request.

Comment: Rather than change this question, post an answer to [this other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live?cb=1).

Comment: Thanks, someone already noticed the problem (of course!) I hope you do not mind I edited a link and suggestion into your answer.

Comment: The proposed wording is still much too weak.  It still leaves an newbie user with a vague impression that they can still ask it.  There needs to be some very strong guidance and large "WARNING" banners about questions of this type are typically not well received unless they are written well

Comment: [I *told* them to remove this option.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378133/1394393)

Comment: The language used in the tip is way too convoluted for someone asking for "hamework help" to understand.

Comment: There should also be an option of I do not know what this code is supposed to do, nor what it does, nor do i know what i'm asking. We see a lot of questions where something isn't working according to OP, but they don't specify in what way it's not working, or what it's supposed to do so it wastes a lot of time trying to work out what it is that the person's asking. Frequently these go into onhold for further information. Also maybe hamwork questions are questions that invite spam ?!