# Are questions that do not contain code always inappropriate?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, dupehammer

I was recently chastised by a fellow member who also unilaterally closed my question on SO because it, "does not contain a minimum, verifiable, etc." piece of code.  I'm not seeking to debate that specific question here, but rather I'd like to get the community's opinion on non-code questions in general.

Certainly, most questions lend themselves to specific code examples.  However, I see value in (and was asking) a question that involves the particularly behavior of an API and the fact that this behavior changes when used in the context of another environment.  I do not believe that these specifics are the only case where a question that *does not contain code* would remain perfectly valid.

In other words, is it appropriate for a user with privileges to unilaterally close a question simply because it does not contain code?  Am I wrong to believe that there are *some* non-code questions that are still appropriate?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56917462/11682469)? It was closed as a *duplicate*.

Comment: Also.... 'chastised'? Are there deleted comments?

Comment: Afaik, noone except diamond moderators can close questions with just one vote for something else than being a duplicate. So either your questions wasn't closed due to missing code or there were several people (or mods) involved.

Comment: _"who also unilaterally closed my question on SO because it, "does not contain a minimum, verifiable, etc." piece of code"_ -- that is a complete and disingenuous mischaracterization of what happened. I closed your question because it was a duplicate of numerous other questions that already exist here, i.e. the ones asking why when they perform a receive operation on a socket, they receive fewer bytes than they expected. The only reason an MCVE came up was in the context of suggesting that if you believe the question was not a duplicate of all those other questions (and many more), ...

Comment: ... that it behooves you to provide more information in your question than you already had, justifying the claim that whatever you are seeing is in fact different, and that a [mcve] would be part of such justification.

Comment: As for "chastise", I guess that's in the eye of the beholder. I didn't write anything that I would consider "chastising", or being personally critical in any way for that matter, but people who feel wronged or are being corrected often take things personally, so I can't say I'm surprised you feel you were chastised. I can only suggest, try not to take things so personally.

Answer (score 6):

No, codeless questions are not necessarily inappropriate. As I've noted before at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378221/1709587 and in [a comment on that same answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378057/the-ask-question-wizard-is-now-in-testing?cb=1#comment658433_378221), when you look at our top-voted questions of all time, or even the top-voted questions in the last year, you find that a large proportion don't contain any code by even by a maximally inclusive definition that counts shell commands or single inline backticked identifiers as "code", and a *majority* don't contain a code block.

As for whatever specific question you got "chastised" about, I haven't seen it and will withhold judgement.

Answer (score 4):

Questions that doesn't include the necessary information to fully answer them are never appropriate. Those questions should be closed as unclear as fast as possible. Now, "code" is not always the information a question may lack. As such, unless you have a crystal ball and remotely figure out what the problem is and provide an answer, every question should contain the necessary information that allows anyone knowledgeable to provide the optimal solution.